# kubernetes cannot pull local image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I am using kubernetes on a single machine for testing, I have built a custom image from the nginx docker image, but when I try to use the image in kubernetes I get an image pull error?????

**MY POD YAML**

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: yumserver
  labels:
    name: frontendhttp
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myfrontend
      image: my/nginx:latest
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
        name: mypd
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: myregistrykey

  volumes:
    - name: mypd
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: myclaim-1
```

**MY KUBERNETES COMMAND**

kubectl create -f pod-yumserver.yaml

**THE ERROR**

```
kubectl describe pod yumserver


Name: yumserver
Namespace: default
Image(s):   my/nginx:latest
Node:       127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1
Start Time: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 16:31:42 +0100
Labels:     name=frontendhttp
Status:     Pending
Reason:     
Message:    
IP:     172.17.0.2
Controllers:    <none>
Containers:
  myfrontend:
    Container ID:   
    Image:      my/nginx:latest
    Image ID:       
    QoS Tier:
      memory:       BestEffort
      cpu:      BestEffort
    State:      Waiting
      Reason:       ErrImagePull
    Ready:      False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment Variables:
Conditions:
  Type      Status
  Ready     False 
Volumes:
  mypd:
    Type:   PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  myclaim-1
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-64w08:
    Type:   Secret (a secret that should populate this volume)
    SecretName: default-token-64w08
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubobjectPath           Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------           --------    ------          -------
  13s       13s     1   {default-scheduler }                    Normal      Scheduled       Successfully assigned yumserver to 127.0.0.1
  13s       13s     1   {kubelet 127.0.0.1}                 Warning     MissingClusterDNS   kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured and cannot create Pod using "ClusterFirst" policy. Falling back to DNSDefault policy.
  12s       12s     1   {kubelet 127.0.0.1} spec.containers{myfrontend} Normal      Pulling         pulling image "my/nginx:latest"
  8s        8s      1   {kubelet 127.0.0.1} spec.containers{myfrontend} Warning     Failed          Failed to pull image "my/nginx:latest": Error: image my/nginx:latest not found
  8s        8s      1   {kubelet 127.0.0.1}                 Warning     FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "myfrontend" with ErrImagePull: "Error: image my/nginx:latest not found"
```

Comment: I could resolve the issue by following https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/local-registry/

Answer (score 89):

> So you have the image on your machine aready. It still tries to pull the image from Docker Hub, however, which is likely not what you want on your single-machine setup. This is happening because the latest tag sets the imagePullPolicy to Always implicitly. You can try setting it to IfNotPresent explicitly or change to a tag other than latest. – Timo Reimann Apr 28 at 7:16

For some reason Timo Reimann did only post this above as a comment, but it definitely should be the official answer to this question, so I'm posting it again.

Comment: BTW IMHO you should always specify a version anyway. Makes everything a lot more predictable...

Comment: To set the `imagePullPolicy` to `IfNotPresent` you can edit the deployment configuration by running 
```bash
$ kubectl edit deployment <deployment-name>
```

Comment: I am getting this error with this answer: ErrImagePull

Comment: as @Martin Rauscher suggested I changed the image tag from latest and explicitly added imagePullPolicy to IfNotPresent for first try find image locally behavior.

see kubernetes documentation about implicit fetching image behavior: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/

Comment: For me, changing only the tag didn't help. But setting the `imagePullPolicy` to `IfNotPresent` + `latest` tag, solved the problem.

Comment: It's the second time this ends up saving me. Double upvote.

Answer (score 63):

Although it is not mentioned in the OP, if you are running `minikube` with the docker driver, and you build your image on your host machine, the pods running in the minikube docker container can't access this image on the host machine.

Run `eval $(minikube docker-env)`, and build your image again.  This simply sets some environment variables in your current shell to point the docker client to the docker host that is running the minikube K8s cluster.

Full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40150867

Comment: minikube is not mentioned being used

Comment: this is important to consider too.

Comment: For Windows see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-to-use-local-docker-images-with-minikube/48999680#comment111474088_48999680

Comment: This is actually relevant to my scenario

Comment: I regularly come back to this question and find this solution. Is there a good place to automate this step? For example in source venv/bin/activate?

Answer (score 39):

This should work irrespective of whether you are using minikube or not :

1. Start a local registry container:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

2. Do `docker images` to find out the REPOSITORY and TAG of your local image. Then create a new tag for your local image :

```
docker tag <local-image-repository>:<local-image-tag> localhost:5000/<local-image-name>
```

If TAG for your local image is `<none>`, you can simply do:

```
docker tag <local-image-repository> localhost:5000/<local-image-name>
```

3. Push to local registry :

```
docker push localhost:5000/<local-image-name>
```

This will automatically add the `latest` tag to `localhost:5000/<local-image-name>`.
You can check again by doing `docker images`.

4. In your yaml file, set `imagePullPolicy` to `IfNotPresent` :

```
...
spec:
  containers:
  - name: <name>
    image: localhost:5000/<local-image-name>
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
...
```

That's it. Now your ImagePullError should be resolved.

**Note**: If you have multiple hosts in the cluster, and you want to use a specific one to host the registry, just replace `localhost` in all the above steps with the hostname of the host where the registry container is hosted. In that case, you may need to allow HTTP (non-HTTPS) connections to the registry:

5 (optional). Allow connection to insecure registry in worker nodes:

```
sudo echo '{"insecure-registries":["<registry-hostname>:5000"]}' > /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

Comment: I opinion is docker registry is a better solution instead of a kind of hack like thing as imagePullPolicy: Never

Comment: None of the above worked for me. Thanks a lot this one actually worked. 
It should be in top.

Comment: I found this background helpful: https://linuxhint.com/setup_own_docker_image_repository/.

Answer (score 17):

just add imagePullPolicy to your deployment file
it worked for me

```
 spec:
  containers:
  - name: <name>
    image: <local-image-name>
    imagePullPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Error: Container image "[CONTAINER]" is not present with pull policy of Never.

Comment: @Riz, same error I am also facing, did you already solve this issue?

Comment: @shivam , same error here, did you managed to sort it out  ?

Comment: @McLan yes, i deleted the deployments(with pod) and the configmap also and before creating a new configmap and deployment i executing the command: eval $(minikube docker-env).

Comment: Thanks @shivam . I am not on minikube. So I doubt the last step applies !

Comment: I am also getting the same error... even after i completly deleted the deployment

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to further analysis `ErrImagePull` problems is to ssh into the node and try to pull the image manually by doing `docker pull my/nginx:latest`. I've never set up Kubernetes on a single machine but could imagine that the Docker daemon isn't reachable from the node for some reason. A handish pull attempt should provide more information.

Comment: docker pull my/nginx:latest
Trying to pull repository docker.io/my/nginx ... failed
Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/my/nginx/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io: No address associated with hostname

Comment: docker images
REPOSITORY                         TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
my/nginx                          latest              04938de4965a        2 weeks ago         182.6 MB

Comment: So you have the image on your machine aready. It still tries to pull the image from Docker Hub, however, which is likely not what you want on your single-machine setup. This is happening because the `latest` tag sets the `imagePullPolicy` to `Always` implicitly. You can try setting it to `IfNotPresent` explicitly or change to a tag other than `latest`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a vm driver, you will need to tell Kubernetes to use the Docker daemon running inside of the single node cluster instead of the host.

Run the following command:

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

Note - This command will need to be repeated anytime you close and restart the terminal session.

Afterward, you can build your image:

```
docker build -t USERNAME/REPO .
```

Update, your pod manifest as shown above and then run:

```
kubectl apply -f myfile.yaml
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Failed to pull image "USERNAME/REPO": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for USERNAME/REPO, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: You need to use your own username and repo name and not just USERNAME and REPO

Answer (score 4):

in your case your yaml file should have
imagePullPolicy: Never
see below

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: yumserver
  labels:
name: frontendhttp
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myfrontend
      image: my/nginx:latest
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
        name: mypd
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: myregistrykey

  volumes:
    - name: mypd
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: myclaim-1
```

found this here
https://keepforyourself.com/docker/run-a-kubernetes-pod-locally/

Answer (score 2):

Are you using minikube on linux? You need to install docker ( I think), but you don't need to start it. Minikube will do that. Try using the KVM driver with this command:

```
minikube start --vm-driver kvm
```

Then run the `eval $(minikube docker-env)` command to make sure you use the minikube docker environment. build your container with a tag `build -t mycontainername:version .`

if you then type `docker ps` you should see a bunch of minikube containers already running. 
kvm utils are probably already on your machine, but they can be installed like this on centos/rhel:

```
yum install qemu-kvm qemu-img virt-manager libvirt libvirt-python
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your "Kubernetes Context" in Docker Desktop is actually a "docker-desktop" (i.e. not a remote cluster).

(Right click on Docker icon, then select "Kubernetes" in menu)

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is just do a docker build from your dockerfile, or get all the images on the nodes of your cluster, do a suitable docker tag and create the manifest.

Kubernetes doesn't directly pull from the registry. First it searches for the image on local storage and then docker registry.

1. Pull latest nginx image

   **docker pull nginx**

   **docker tag nginx:latest test:test8970**
2. Create a deployment
   `kubectl run test --image=test:test8970`
   It won't go to docker registry to pull the image. It will bring up the pod instantly.
   [image]
3. And if **image is not present on local machine** it will try to pull from docker registry and fail with **ErrImagePull** error.
   [image]
4. Also if you change the **imagePullPolicy: Never**. It will never look for the registry to pull the image and will fail if image is not found with error **ErrImageNeverPull**.
   [image]

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: test
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: test
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: test:test8070
        name: test
        imagePullPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 1):

### ContainerD (and Windows)

I had the same error, while trying to run a custom windows container on a node. I had `imagePullPolicy` set to `Never` and a locally existing image present on the node. The image also wasn't tagged with `latest`, so the comment from Timo Reimann wasn't relevant.

Also, on the node machine, the image showed up when using `nerdctl image`. However they didn't show up in `crictl images`.

Thanks to a [comment on Github](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/issues/546#issuecomment-646909445), I found out that the actual problem is a different namespace of ContainerD.

As shown by the following two commands, images are not automatically build in the correct namespace:

```
ctr -n default images ls    # shows the application images (wrong namespace)
ctr -n k8s.io images ls     # shows the base images
```

To solve the problem, export and reimport the images to the correct namespace `k8s.io` by using the following command:

```
ctr --namespace k8s.io image import exported-app-image.tar
```

Comment: I tried this and successfully imported, as the image shows up with ctr -n k8s.io images ls  However, I don't know how to access it from the pod template  Should I use image:k8s.io/image-name or just the bare image name?  I tried both but it would not pull the image.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer here as the above gave me enough to figure out the cause of my particular instance of this issue. Turns out that my build process was missing the tagging needed to make `:latest` work. As soon as I added a `<tags>` section to my *docker-maven-plugin* configuration in my *pom.xml*, everything was hunky-dory. Here's some example configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.27.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <images>
            <image>
                <name>akka-cluster-demo:${docker.image.version}</name>
                <build>
                    <from>openjdk:8-jre-alpine</from>
```

Adding this:

```
                    <tags>
                        <tag>latest</tag>
                        <tag>${git.commit.version}</tag>
                    </tags>
```

The rest continues as before:

```
                    <ports>
                        <port>8080</port>
                        <port>8558</port>
                        <port>2552</port>
                    </ports>
                    <entryPoint>
                        <exec>
                            <args>/bin/sh</args>
                            <args>-c</args>
                            <args>java -jar /maven/cluster-sharding-kubernetes.jar</args>
                        </exec>
                    </entryPoint>
                    <assembly>
                        <inline>
                            <dependencySets>
                                <dependencySet>
                                    <useProjectAttachments>true</useProjectAttachments>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>akka-java:cluster-sharding-kubernetes:jar:allinone</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <outputFileNameMapping>cluster-sharding-kubernetes.jar</outputFileNameMapping>
                                </dependencySet>
                            </dependencySets>
                        </inline>
                    </assembly>
                </build>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue but I'm using Minikube and I have solved it by loading image in Minikube

```
minikube image load <img-name>:<tag>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing similar issue .Image was present in local but k8s was not able to pick it up.
So I went to terminal ,deleted the old image and ran eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env) command.
Rebuilt the image and the redeployed the deployment yaml ,and it worked

Comment: Question assumes that minikube is not used.

Comment: eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)  uses minikube as param

Comment: My mistake. I can't see now why using docker-env wouldn't help in a single node case. With multiple nodes it is not supposed to work anyway. Btw, I can't upvote unless you edit the answer (..)