# Why am I getting an ErrImagePull error in this Kubernetes deployment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I'm trying to create a local Kubernetes deployment using Minikube, Docker Registry, and a demo node project.

The first thing I did was install Docker v1.12.3, then Minikube v0.12.2.

Then I created a Docker Registry container by running this command (via [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/registry/), only running the first command below)

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2
```

Next I ran this minikube command to create a local kubernetes cluster:

```
minikube start --vm-driver="virtualbox" --insecure-registry="0.0.0.0:5000"
```

My project structure looks like this:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── server.js
```

and my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:7.1.0
EXPOSE 8080
COPY server.js .
CMD node server.js
```

Then I built my own docker image and pushed it to my private repository:

```
docker build -t hello-node .
docker tag hello-node localhost:5000/hello-node
docker push localhost:5000/hello-node
```

Then I tried to run a deployment with this command:

```
kubectl run hello-node --image=localhost:5000/hello-node --port=8888
```

But then I get this:

```
sudo kubectl get pods --all-namespaces                                                                                                                             
NAMESPACE     NAME                          READY     STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
default       hello-node-3745105022-gzs5a   0/1       ErrImagePull   0          11m
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube   1/1       Running        4          10d
kube-system   kube-dns-v20-2x64k            3/3       Running        12         10d
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-mjpjv    1/1       Running        4          10d
```

I think I might be missing some kind of docker registry authentication, but as I'm googling I can't find something that I understand. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

**Edit**

After using ssh to access `bash` on the kubernetes VM and pull the `hello-node` image from my private registry by using this command:

```
minikube ssh
Boot2Docker version 1.11.1, build master : 901340f - Fri Jul  1 
22:52:19 UTC 2016
Docker version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe
docker@minikube:~$ sudo docker pull localhost:5000/hello-node
Using default tag: latest
Pulling repository localhost:5000/hello-node
Error while pulling image: Get http://localhost:5000/v1/repositories/hello-node/images: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Is `localhost:5000` the correct address to use within the kubernetes host VM?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36874880/2051454

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It looks like you're running the registry on the host.  In fact, you need to run the registry inside the VM.  You can point your docker client to the docker daemon inside the minikube VM by running this command first

`eval $(minikube docker-env)`

in your shell.

Then, you can run the docker build command on your host, but it will build inside the VM.

In fact, if your goal is to simply run the local version of your images, you should run the `eval $(minikube docker-env)` to point towards the docker daemon in your VM, and set the `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent` in your pod YAML.  Then, kubernetes will use a locally built image if available.

Comment: what is the windows powershell equivalent?

Comment: I hit this question I had the same thought in my mind as @user3335999 . A bit of digging, the windows 10 equivalent is `minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression`. Source: [this web page](https://medium.com/@maumribeiro/running-your-own-docker-images-in-minikube-for-windows-ea7383d931f6)

Comment: I tried all this but I'm still getting:

Failed to pull image "5ccf6e9a71a8": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 5ccf6e9a71a8, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Answer (score 9):

Had a same issue with `Docker-Desktop > Kubernetes` and I tried setting `imagePullPolicy` to `Never` and it just worked.

As I understood from `kubectl describe pod mypd`, `Kubectl` was trying to pull  the image, and of course this image doesn't exist on remote server, hence the failure.

The above property will avoid connecting to registry and will use image from docker local images cache.

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: my/local-image
          imagePullPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 2):

This article has resolved my similar error
https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-run-locally-built-docker-images-in-kubernetes-b28fbc32cc1d

Add `imagePullPolicy: Never`

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: hello-world-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-world
        image: forketyfork/hello-world
        imagePullPolicy: Never
      restartPolicy: Never
```

After that link your local container registry to minikube docker container registry.

Run the below command:

`eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)`

Now build your docker image and kubectl service again
, That's it !

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps, for minikube

1. Update values.yaml with `pullPolicy: IfNotPresent`
2. Manually upload image in minikube using `minikube image load`
3. Verify if image is uploaded using ssh in minikube vm
4. Uninstall and reinstall existing deployment. You can see your existing deploymet using `kubectl get deployment -w`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this question has already been answered.

Comment: @NathanJones Okk, I am sorry, But I Just wanted to contribute an answer to this question for StackOverflow community. And,  it's just that I discovered a different unique solution that wasn't already here except for the first step. This is also a very common problem related to kubernetes. And the solution that has been marked accepted didn't work for me. Thanks

Comment: You're right, sorry for the passive aggressive comment. Thanks for sharing what worked for you!