# kubectl get pods ErrImagePull

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm fighting with Kubernetes.  I've googled a lot and looked at a few answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600419/why-am-i-getting-an-errimagepull-error-in-this-kubernetes-deployment) - for example - but can't seem to get it to work.

I've created a docker container and push to local registry:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2
sudo docker tag i-a/i-a:latest localhost:5000/i-a
sudo docker push localhost:5000/i-a
```

The last command gives:

```
The push refers to a repository [localhost:5000/i-a]
e0a33c56cca0: Pushed 
54ab83ede54d: Pushed 
f5a58f369605: Pushed 
cd7100a72410: Pushed 
latest: digest: sha256:0f30cdf6b4a4e0e382a6cae50c1325103c3b987d9e51c42edea2244a82ae1331 size: 1164
```

Doing `sudo docker pull localhost:5000/i-a` gives:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from i-a
Digest: sha256:0f30cdf6b4a4e0e382a6cae50c1325103c3b987d9e51c42edea2244a82ae1331
Status: Image is up to date for localhost:5000/i-a:latest
```

The config file i-a.yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: i-a
  name: i-a
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: i-a
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: i-a
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: localhost:5000/i-a
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: i-a
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8090
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: i-a
  name: i-a
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8090
  selector:
    run: i-a
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

When I do `sudo kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` I get:

```
...
default       i-a-3400848339-0x6c9   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          13m
default       i-a-3400848339-7ltp1   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          13m
default       i-a-3400848339-wv092   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          13m
```

The `ImagePullBackOff` turns to `ErrImagePull`.

When I run `kubectl describe pod i-a-3400848339-0x6c9` I get an error `Failed to pull image "localhost:5000/i-a": Error while pulling image: Get http://localhost:5000/v1/repositories/i-a/images: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: getsockopt: connection refused`:

```
Name:       i-a-3400848339-0x6c9
Namespace:  default
Node:       minikube/192.168.99.100
Start Time: Mon, 09 Apr 2018 21:11:15 +0200
Labels:     pod-template-hash=3400848339
        run=i-a
Status:     Pending
IP:     172.17.0.7
Controllers:    ReplicaSet/i-a-3400848339
Containers:
  i-a:
    Container ID:                  
    Image:      localhost:5000/i-a
    Image ID:       
    Port:       8090/TCP
    State:      Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:      False
    Restart Count:  0
    Volume Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-bmwkd (ro)
    Environment Variables:  <none>
Conditions:
  Type      Status
  Initialized   True 
  Ready     False 
  PodScheduled  True 
Volumes:
  default-token-bmwkd:
    Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-bmwkd
QoS Class:  BestEffort
Tolerations:    <none>
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubobjectPath               Type        Reason      Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------               --------    ------      -------
  18m       18m     1   {default-scheduler }                        Normal      Scheduled   Successfully assigned i-a-3400848339-0x6c9 to minikube
  18m       2m      8   {kubelet minikube}  spec.containers{i-a}    Normal      Pulling     pulling image "localhost:5000/i-a"
  18m       2m      8   {kubelet minikube}  spec.containers{i-a}    Warning     Failed      Failed to pull image "localhost:5000/i-a": Error while pulling image: Get http://localhost:5000/v1/repositories/i-a/images: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: getsockopt: connection refused
  18m       2m      8   {kubelet minikube}                      Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "i-a" with ErrImagePull: "Error while pulling image: Get http://localhost:5000/v1/repositories/i-a/images: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: getsockopt: connection refused"

  18m   13s 75  {kubelet minikube}  spec.containers{i-a}    Normal  BackOff     Back-off pulling image "localhost:5000/i-a"
  18m   13s 75  {kubelet minikube}                      Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "i-a" with ImagePullBackOff: "Back-off pulling image \"localhost:5000/i-a\""
```

I'm not sure where to look next...
(I get 404 when I browse to http://localhost:5000/v1/repositories/i-a/images)

Comment: Remove "localhost:5000/" from Image under Spec/containers, and set ImagePullPolicy to Never. It should allow you to pull this image from your local registry. Of course, this image will be available only to node which hosts your docker private registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - image: localhost:5000/i-a
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        name: i-a
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8090
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
```