# ErrImagePull when helm installing fluentbit

Tags: docker, minikube, fluent-bit

I was trying to reinstall fluentbit on a minikube cluster running on my local machine by following the steps in https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/kubernetes#installing-with-helm-chart. I've been able to get fluentbit deployed in the past by following the same process, but for some reason after I edited the configmap and re-applied it as a daemonset (a workflow that I've used successfully in the past), the pod's status is ErrImagePull.

I've tried
• The solution in [Why am I getting an ErrImagePull error in this Kubernetes deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600419/why-am-i-getting-an-errimagepull-error-in-this-kubernetes-deployment) (although I'm not sure if it was relevant as I'm not building a docker image myself).
• Deleting my fluent-bit configmap and daemonset and reinstalling with helm chart.
Neither seemed to work.

I've attached the output of running `kubectl describe pods` [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCfxp.jpg). I'd appreciate some help with this issue, thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try to pull any other public image into your cluster? Since the image you've specified should be accessible without authentication, it's worth checking if your cluster has access to the docker registry hosting the fluent-bit image.

Comment: Update - I'm not sure how, but the problem seems to be resolved now (made no changes/did nothing different since I posted about it). Thanks.