# How can I use local Docker images with Minikube?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, minikube

I have several Docker images that I want to use with [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/). I don't want to first have to upload and then download the same image instead of just using the local image directly. How do I do this?

Stuff I tried:

1. I tried running these commands (separately, deleting the instances of Minikube both times and starting fresh)

```
kubectl run hdfs --image=fluxcapacitor/hdfs:latest --port=8989
kubectl run hdfs --image=fluxcapacitor/hdfs:latest --port=8989 imagePullPolicy=Never
```

Output:

```
NAME                    READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
hdfs-2425930030-q0sdl   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          10m
```

It just gets stuck on some status but never reaches the ready state.

2. I tried creating a registry and then putting images into it, but that didn't work either. I might've done that incorrectly but I can't find proper instructions to do this task.

Please provide instructions to use local Docker images in a local Kubernetes instance.

OS: [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) 
Docker: Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3 
Kubernetes:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.3", GitCommit:"029c3a408176b55c30846f0faedf56aae5992e9b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-02-15T06:40:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

What is a solution that uses docker-compose to do this?

Images loaded in `eval $(minikube docker-env)`:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.3", GitCommit:"029c3a408176b55c30846f0faedf56aae5992e9b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-02-15T06:40:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

What is a solution that uses docker-compose to do this?

Images loaded in `eval $(minikube docker-env)`:

```
REPOSITORY                                           TAG     IMAGE ID      CREATED       SIZE
fluxcapacitor/jupyterhub                             latest  e5175fb26522  4 weeks ago   9.59 GB
fluxcapacitor/zeppelin                               latest  fe4bc823e57d  4 weeks ago   4.12 GB
fluxcapacitor/prediction-pmml                        latest  cae5b2d9835b  4 weeks ago   973 MB
fluxcapacitor/scheduler-airflow                      latest  95adfd56f656  4 weeks ago   8.89 GB
fluxcapacitor/loadtest                               latest  6a777ab6167c  5 weeks ago   899 MB
fluxcapacitor/hdfs                                   latest  00fa0ed0064b  6 weeks ago   1.16 GB
fluxcapacitor/sql-mysql                              latest  804137671a8c  7 weeks ago   679 MB
fluxcapacitor/metastore-1.2.1                        latest  ea7ce8c5048f  7 weeks ago   1.35 GB
fluxcapacitor/cassandra                              latest  3cb5ff117283  7 weeks ago   953 MB
fluxcapacitor/apachespark-worker-2.0.1               latest  14ee3e4e337c  7 weeks ago   3.74 GB
fluxcapacitor/apachespark-master-2.0.1               latest  fe60b42d54e5  7 weeks ago   3.72 GB
fluxcapacitor/package-java-openjdk-1.8               latest  1db08965289d  7 weeks ago   841 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64  v1.5.1  1180413103fd  7 weeks ago   104 MB
fluxcapacitor/stream-kafka-0.10                      latest  f67750239f4d  2 months ago  1.14 GB
fluxcapacitor/pipeline                               latest  f6afd6c5745b  2 months ago  11.2 GB
gcr.io/google-containers/kube-addon-manager          v6.1    59e1315aa5ff  3 months ago  59.4 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/kubedns-amd64               1.9     26cf1ed9b144  3 months ago  47 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/kube-dnsmasq-amd64          1.4     3ec65756a89b  5 months ago  5.13 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz-amd64           1.2     93a43bfb39bf  5 months ago  8.37 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64
```

Comment: Why doesn't the last row have values for the last four columns?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 6 years ago"*

Answer (score 778, accepted):

As [the handbook](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/#1-pushing-directly-to-the-in-cluster-docker-daemon-docker-env) describes, you can reuse the Docker daemon from Minikube with `eval $(minikube docker-env)`.

So to use an image without uploading it, you can follow these steps:

1. Set the environment variables with `eval $(minikube docker-env)`
2. Build the image with the Docker daemon of Minikube (e.g., `docker build -t my-image .`)
3. Set the image in the pod specification like the build tag (e.g., `my-image`)
4. Set the [`imagePullPolicy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images) to `Never`, otherwise Kubernetes will try to download the image.

**Important note:** You have to run `eval $(minikube docker-env)` on each terminal you want to use, since it only sets the environment variables for the current shell session.

Comment: How do I increase the space in docker after `eval $(minikube docker-env)`? After adding a few images, it says that no more space is available in the docker.

Comment: AFAIS you can only do that with a new minukube with `minikube start --disk-size 100g`. Another solution would be to delete old images with `docker images` and `docker rmi`.

Comment: Could't able to build image after step 1. then I did minikube stop and minikube start . I can now able to build image(step 2)

Comment: Very important to remember to run `eval $(minikube docker-env)` after closing the terminal you're working in BEFORE you try to rebuild images... just burned 6 hours fighting with an image that was not updating in minikube... looked like a package was not updating... really just not updating the image that minikube was referencing.

Comment: The default pull policy is `IfNotPresent` which means all we have to do is to set the environment variables.

Comment: If u wanna back or exit env from minikube.. `eval $(minikube docker-env -u)`

Comment: How can I  "Set the ```imagePullPolicy``` to ```Never```" using ```kubectl``` ?

Comment: @nmxl look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-to-use-local-docker-images-with-minikube/42564058#48999680)

Comment: Nowdays, you can also use `minikube cache add imagename:tag` to push the image to the minikube - be sure to include the tag as well. [Docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/#2-push-images-using-cache-command)

Comment: @miha Very useful link. Full operational solution with add, delete and list options. For me, for now that is the best answear.

Comment: For windows what do i do to run eval $(minikube docker-env)

Comment: `"minikube cache" will be deprecated in upcoming versions, please switch to "minikube image load"` - just got it from my terminal.

Comment: The docs explains this way in [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/#1-pushing-directly-to-the-in-cluster-docker-daemon-docker-env)

Comment: What about docker desktop? How can we use local docker images in docker desktops kubernetes?

Comment: @Varun It works directly with dkr desktop k8s, just use `image_name:tag` (don't specify repo) and it will use local image

Comment: Use `kubectl edit deployment <deployment_name>` to edit the yaml file that contains the `imagePullPolicy`. This wasn't obvious from the official docs

Answer (score 311):

What worked for me, based on [the solution by svenwltr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-can-i-use-local-docker-images-with-minikube/42564211#42564211):

```
# Start minikube
minikube start

# Set docker env
eval $(minikube docker-env)             # Unix shells
minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression # PowerShell

# Build image
docker build -t foo:0.0.1 .

# Run in Minikube
kubectl run hello-foo --image=foo:0.0.1 --image-pull-policy=Never

# Check that it's running
kubectl get pods
```

Comment: You can find the yml version of the above command line (in regards to the imagePullPolicy) here : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/

Comment: On Windows eval $(minikube docker-env) was not working for me. 
minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression seems to work in PowerShell. In other terminals one needs to read the last line returned by minikube docker-env. For example, in IntelliJ (on Windows) it is @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env') DO @%i  You have to do this in any new terminal/session always before building the docker image.

Comment: I am getting following error while doing eval $(minikube docker-env).

"'none' driver does not support 'minikube docker-env' command"

It is also logged on github it seems.

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2443

Answer (score 294):

There is one easy and effective way to push your local Docker image directly to Minikube, which will save time from building the images in Minikube again.

```
minikube image load <image name>
```

(*`minikube cache add <image name>`*—the old deprecated way, for reference)

More details are [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/#2-push-images-using-cache-command).

All possible method to push images to Minikube are mention here: *[Pushing images](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/)*

Comment: This answer should be higher in the list, it is the more up-to-date solution.

Comment: I wonder why it's so slow. Sometimes it gets cancelled. Maybe not enough RAM

Comment: There are sorting tabs at the top of the answers section, you probably selected one you're not used to, the best to choose is "Trending"

Comment: Is there a way to force a pod to pick up the new image when I upload it into minikube repeatedly? Every time I upload a new image version with the same name/tag the pod keeps working on the old image until I delete the image explicitly in minikube and load it again.

Comment: for anybody reading this anwer: it won't work without `imagePullPolicy: Never` If you check out the logs you'll see that minikube is trying to pull the image even if it knows about it (`minikube image ls`)

Answer (score 169):

#### Notes:

- **This answer isn’t limited to Minikube!**
- **If wanting to create the registry on Minikube's Docker** then run `eval $(minikube docker-env)` first (to make `docker` available on the host machine's terminal).
  Otherwise, enter in the virtual machine via `minikube ssh`, and then proceed with the following steps
- depending on your operative system, [Minikube will automatically mount your homepath](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/#driver-mounts) onto the VM.
- as Eli stated, you'll need to add the local registry as insecure in order to use [http](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure) (may not apply when using localhost, but it does apply if using the local hostname).
  **Don't use http in production. Make the effort for securing things up.**

---

Use a local registry:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name local-registry registry:2
```

Now tag your image properly:

```
docker tag ubuntu localhost:5000/ubuntu
```

Note that *localhost* should be changed to the DNS name of the machine running registry container.

Now push your image to the local registry:

```
docker push localhost:5000/ubuntu
```

You should be able to pull it back:

```
docker pull localhost:5000/ubuntu
```

Now change your YAML file to use the local registry.

Think about mounting volumes at appropriate location, to persist the images on the registry.

Comment: | Now change your yaml file to use the local registry. Are you able to explain this a little bit? I pushed to the local registry (cool trick) but I have the same problem that I can't get minikube to connect to it.

Comment: @ZachEstela change the image name in the yaml to `<registryIP>:5000/ubuntu`

Comment: @FarhadFarahi Where can I find the "dns name of the machine running registry container"?

Comment: @Daan this is what you create so depending how you create it you should know it.

Comment: @FarhadFarahi If I give my laptop to you, how would you find out? I just want to know it. I followed docker tutorial steps to get docker for windows running.

Comment: @daan if you run docker registry on your laptop it would be `yourlaptopip:dockerregistryport`

Comment: @FarhadFarahi: Please add to your answer that you'll need to add the local registry as insecure in order to use http: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/ (may not apply when using localhost but does apply if using the local hostname).

Comment: Failed to pull image "localhost:5000/src_interface:latest" according to my minikube dashboard, this doesn't seem to work. How would kubectl even access port 5000?

Comment: Great answer! Can you please elaborate about what to mount, in order to source (and backup) the images on the host machine? – *E.g.* minikube mounts macOS's `/Users/` dir on the VM; so host folders become available for potentially being mounted further (via `docker`) on the *local-registry* container; see my edits to your answer.

Comment: [I figured out! See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67030771/3088045); hopefully will make life your travelling digital nomad life a little happier! 

Answer (score 26):

Adding to to [Farhad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-can-i-use-local-docker-images-with-minikube/42564191#42564191) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46068235/3701807),

These are the steps to set up a local registry.

**Set up in local machine**

Set up the hostname in the local machine: edit `/etc/hosts` to add this line:

```
docker.local 127.0.0.1
```

Now start a local registry (remove `-d` to run non-daemon mode):

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

Now tag your image properly:

```
docker tag ubuntu docker.local:5000/ubuntu
```

Now push your image to the local registry:

```
docker push docker.local:5000/ubuntu
```

Verify that the image is pushed:

```
curl -X GET http://docker.local:5000/v2/ubuntu/tags/list
```

**Set up in Minikube**

SSH into Minikube with: `minukube ssh`

Edit [/etc/hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) to add this line:

```
docker.local <your host machine's IP address>
```

Verify access:

```
curl -X GET http://docker.local:5000/v2/ubuntu/tags/list
```

Now if you try to pull, yo might get an http access error.

**Enable insecure access**:

If you are always planning to use Minikube with this local setup then create a Minikube instance to use the insecure registry by default (it won’t work on an existing cluster).

```
minikube start --insecure-registry="docker.local:5000"
```

Else follow the below steps:

```
systemctl stop docker
```

Edit the Docker serice file: get path from `systemctl status docker`

It might be:

> /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/10-machine.conf  or
> /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service

Append this text (replace 192.168.1.4 with your IP address)

```
--insecure-registry docker.local:5000 --insecure-registry 192.168.1.4:5000
```

to this line

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --tlsverify --tlscacert /etc/docker/ca.pem --tlscert /etc/docker/server.pem --tlskey /etc/docker/server-key.pem --label provider=virtualbox --insecure-registry 10.0.0.0/24
```

And:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start docker
```

Try pulling:

```
docker pull docker.local:5000/ubuntu
```

Now change your YAML file to use the local registry.

```
containers:
  - name: ampl-django
       image: dockerhub/ubuntu
```

to

```
containers:
  - name: ampl-django
    image: docker.local:5000/nymbleup
```

**Don't use http in production. Make the effort for securing things up.**

Comment: What is *"Docker serice file"*? Is it *"Docker service file"*? Or something else?

Answer (score 17):

Newer versions of Minikube allows you to load an image from the local Docker instance by running:

```
minikube image rm image <imagename>:<version>
minikube image load <imagename>:<version> --daemon
```

The *load* command might show an error, but the image still gets loaded to your Minikube instance.

Comment: this seems to be a great answer ... do you have any sources ?

Comment: just found reference here:https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/#7-loading-directly-to-in-cluster-container-runtime ... the --daemon option is not really needed.

Comment: How long does it take? Its running since 20 minutes for 645MB image

Answer (score 15):

One thing to remember regarding Minikube is that Minikube's host is not the same as your local host, therefore, what I realized, that in order to use local images for testing with Minikube you must build your Docker image first locally or pull it locally and then add it using the command below into the Minikube context which is, nothing else as another Linux instance.

```
 minikube cache add <image>:<tag>
```

Yet, don't forget to set the `imagePullPolicy: Never` in your Kubernetes deployment YAML files, as it will ensure using locally added images instead of trying pull it remotely from the registry.

Note: `minikube cache` will be deprecated in upcoming versions. Please switch to `minikube image load`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 13):

One approach is to build the image locally and then do:

```
docker save imageNameGoesHere | pv | (eval $(minikube docker-env) && docker load)
```

`minikube docker-env` might not return the correct info running under a different user / sudo. Instead you can run `sudo -u yourUsername minikube docker-env`.

It should return something like:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/home/chris/.minikube/certs"
export DOCKER_API_VERSION="1.23"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

Comment: The correct command is `docker save imageNameGoesHere > pv | (eval $(minikube docker-env) && docker load) `

Comment: `docker save imageNameGoesHere | (eval $(minikube docker-env) && docker load)` worked for me

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the accepted answer, you can also achieve what you originally wanted (creating a deployment using the `run` command) with the following command:

```
kubectl run hdfs --image=fluxcapacitor/hdfs:latest --port=8989 --generator=run-pod/v1
```

I found the information about the generator on the Kubernetes-dev forum:

> If you're using `kubectl run`, it generates a manifest for you that happens to have `imagePullPolicy` set to `Always` by default. You can use this command to get an `imagePullPolicy` of `IfNotPresent`, which will work for `minikube`:
>
> `kubectl run --image=<container> --generator=run-pod/v1`
>
> Dan Lorenc

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-dev/YfvWuFr_XOM

Answer (score 10):

If anyone is looking to come back to the local environment after setting the Minikube environment, use the following command.

```
eval $(docker-machine env -u)
```

Comment: Already posted as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-to-use-local-docker-images-with-minikube#comment96193812_42564211

Comment: Would be eval $(minikube docker-env -u) for minikube

Answer (score 9):

A simpler method that answers the question "How can I use local docker images with Minikube?", is to save the image to a tar file and load it into Minikube:

```
# Export the Docker image to a tar file
docker save --output my-image.tar the.full.path.to/the/docker/image:the-tag
# Set local environment variables so that docker commands go to the Docker in Minikube
eval $(minikube docker-env)
# Or if on Windows: @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO @%i
# Import the Docker image from the tar file into Minikube
docker load --input my-image.tar
# Cleanup - put Docker back to normal
eval $(minikube docker-env -u)
# Or if on Windows: @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env -u') DO @%i
```

Then running the image involves a command like the following. Make sure to include the "--image-pull-policy=Never" parameter.

```
kubectl run my-image --image=the.full.path.to/the/docker/image:the-tag --image-pull-policy=Never --port=80
```

Comment: Well explained, worked like a charm. I only had to call `docker save` with `sudo`, and then set `sudo chmod 664 my-image.tar` to make it available for my current user.

Answer (score 7):

From the Kubernetes documentation:

*[Updating images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images)*

> The default pull policy is IfNotPresent which causes the Kubelet to skip pulling an image if it already exists. If you would like to always force a pull, you can do one of the following:
>
> - set the imagePullPolicy of the container to Always;
> - use :latest as the tag for the image to use;
> - enable the AlwaysPullImages admission controller.

Or read the other way:  Using the *:latest* tag forces images to always be pulled.  If you use the `eval $(minikube docker-env)` as mentioned in other answers, then either don't use any tag, or assign a tag to your local image you can avoid Kubernetes trying to forcibly pull it.

Answer (score 7):

One idea would be to save the Docker image locally and later load it into Minikube as follows:

Let’s say, for example, you already have *puckel/docker-airflow* image.

1. Save that image to local disk -

   `docker save puckel/docker-airflow > puckel_docker_airflow.tar`
2. Now enter into the Minikube Docker environment -

   `eval $(minikube docker-env)`
3. Load that locally-saved image -

   `docker load < puckel_docker_airflow.tar`

It is that simple, and it works like a charm.

Comment: You still need the accepted answer's tip of `Set the imagePullPolicy to Never`. If your image is tagged with an address e.g. `us.icr.io/mydiv/my-service:v0.0.1` then a deploy will try to remote pull this image. Since you've already manually copied the image, you need to suppress k8s from pulling the image from an address (container registry) it can't access.

Comment: @colm.anseo The steps above worked for me but I had to replace the `latest` tag in the image with a specific version and select this version in the create deploy command. The `imagePullPolicy` was automatically set to `IfNotPresent` and the image was loaded correctly without further changes.

Answer (score 6):

For Windows users, the way I do it.

I use the [Docker Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)#Adoption) to host my Minikube image and use PowerShell as a console.

First I create my Minikube cluster:

```
minikube start --bootstrapper=kubeadm --vm-driver=docker --profile "cluster1"
```

For instance, let's say I have a `Dockerfile` contains:

```
FROM nginx
```

Two steps way: Build an image and upload the image to Minikube

```
docker build -t mynginximage .
minikube image load mynginximage
```

**Or** a one-step way, build directly in Minikube:

```
minikube image build -t mynginximage .
```

To run my image in Minikube:

```
kubectl run myweb --image=mynginximage --image-pull-policy=Never
```

Or via the `mynginxpod.yaml` file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myweb
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myweb
      image: mynginximage
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

And `kubectl apply -f .\mynginxpod.yaml`

Now to test it, run:

```
kubectl get pods myweb
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
myweb   1/1     Running   0          25s
```

To access it:

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty myweb -- /bin/bash
```

To expose it:

```
kubectl port-forward nginx 3333:80
```

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
minikube addons enable registry -p minikube
```

Output:

```
  Registry addon on with docker uses 32769 please use that instead
  of default 5000 <br>
  For more information see:
  https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker
```

And:

```
docker tag ubuntu $(minikube ip -p minikube):32769/ubuntu
docker push $(minikube ip -p minikube):32769/ubuntu
```

*Or*

```
minikube addons enable registry
docker tag ubuntu $(minikube ip):32769/ubuntu
docker push $(minikube ip):32769/ubuntu
```

The above is good enough for development purposes. I am doing this on [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux).

Comment: How do u refer to the image in the k8s specs? By `localhost:32769/ubuntu` or with the minikube ip or the registry dns name?

Answer (score 4):

There is now a Minikube Registry addon, and this is probably the easiest way. Here is how to use it: *[Registries](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tasks/registry/insecure/)*

Note that I had DNS issues, and it might be a bug.

Comment: The link may or may not be half-broken (it redirects).

Answer (score 4):

You should know that **docker in your local machine** is separated from the **docker in your `minikube` cluster**.

So you should **load/copy** a Docker image from your **local machine** into the **minikube cluster**:

```bash
minikube image load <IMAGE_NAME>
```

or alternatively when working with `minikube`, you can build images directly inside it:

```bash
#instead of:
docker image build -t <IMAGE_NAME> .
#do:
minikube image build -t <IMAGE_NAME> .
```

Comment: `Error: unknown command "build" for "minikube"`; what minikube version are you talking about?

Comment: @Kamafeather 
`minikube version: v1.28.0
commit: 986b1ebd987211ed16f8cc10aed7d2c42fc8392f`
you can install it from [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)

Comment: Oh, we are constrained to an earlier version at the moment, but thank you for the update I'll check it out!

Answer (score 4):

There are two easy ways to load local images to Minikube.

Always make sure to set imagePullPolicy: Never in your deployment yaml.

Eg:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myapp
      image: pz/demo
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Luckily, there are two straightforward commands to help with this.

1. The first one is the image load command. You can load a Docker image from your local machine into the Minikube cluster with the following command.

## General

`minikube image load <IMAGE_NAME>`

## Example

`minikube image load pz/demo`

After loading the image to your Minikube cluster, you can restart your Pods of the above Deployment and notice that they are starting fine.

2. With the previous way, you always build the Docker image on your local machine and then move it to the Minikube container, which again takes a bit of time, even though not a lot.

Using the image build command of Minikube, we can build the image directly inside the Minikube container.

## General

`minikube image build -t <IMAGE_NAME> <PATH_TO_DOCKERFILE>`

## Example

`minikube image build -t pz/demo /New APP/Dockerfile`

Using the minikube image build command the image is instantly available to Minikkube and doesn't have to be explicitly loaded in a second step via the minikube image load command.

Using one of both methods to get our application Docker image into Minikube and restart the Pods, we can recheck the logs of the Deployment:

Further, to verify end to end that everything is working as expected, we can port forward our local port 8080 to the 8080 of the Deployment by using:

`kubectl port-forward deployment/myapp 8080:8080`

Rechecking the browser, we see that the locally built application runs fine on the Minikube cluster.

Ref: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/two-easy-ways-to-use-local-docker-images-in-minikube-cd4dcb1a5379

Answer (score 2):

To add to the previous answers, if you have a [tarball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) image, you can simply load it to you local Docker set of images `docker image load -i /path/image.tar`. Please remember to run it **after** `eval $(minikube docker-env)`, since Minikube does not share images with the locally-installed Docker engine.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers suppose you use Minikube with a VM, so your local images are not accessible from the Minikube VM.

In case if you use Minikube with `--vm-driver=none`, you can easily reuse local images by setting `image_pull_policy` to Never:

```
kubectl run hello-foo --image=foo --image-pull-policy=Never
```

Or setting the `imagePullPolicy` field for containers in corresponding `.yaml` manifests.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to run local Docker images in Kubernetes:

1. `eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)`
2. In the artifact file, under the spec section → *containers.

   Add:

   ```
   imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
   ```

   or

   ```
   imagePullPolicy: Never
   ```

   ```
   apiVersion: "v1"
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
       name: web
       labels:
           name: web
           app: demo
   spec:
       containers:
           - name: web
             image: web:latest
             imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
             ports:
                 - containerPort: 5000
                   name: http
                   protocol: TCP
   ```
3. Then run `kubectl create -f <filename>`

Answer (score 2):

For Minikube on Docker:

Option 1: Using the Minikube registry

1. Check your Minikube ports

   `docker ps`

   You will see something like: `127.0.0.1:32769->5000/tcp`
   It means that your Minikube registry is on the 32769 port for external usage, but internally it's on the 5000 port.
2. Build your Docker image tagging it:

   `docker build -t 127.0.0.1:32769/hello .`
3. Push the image to the Minikube registry:

   `docker push 127.0.0.1:32769/hello`
4. Check if it's there:

   `curl http://localhost:32769/v2/_catalog`
5. Build some deployment using the internal port:

   `kubectl create deployment hello --image=127.0.0.1:5000/hello`

   Your image is right now in the Minikube container. To see it, write:

   ```
   eval $(minikube -p <PROFILE> docker-env)
   docker images
   ```

   Caveat: if using only one profile named "minikube" then "-p " section is redundant, but if using more then don't forget about it. Personally I delete the standard one (Minikube) not to make mistakes.

Option 2: Not using the registry

1. Switch to Minikube container Docker:

   `eval $(minikube -p <PROFILE> docker-env)`
2. Build your image:

   `docker build -t hello .`
3. Create some deployment:

   `kubectl create deployment hello --image=hello`

   At the end, change the deployment *ImagePullPolicy* from *Always* to *IfNotPresent*:

   `kubectl edit deployment hello`

Answer (score 2):

In addition of `minikube image load <image name>`, check out the latest (Nov 2021 at the time of writing) release of Minikube.

[v1.24.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.24.0)

> Add `--no-kubernetes` flag to start minikube without Kubernetes
> See [PR 12848](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/12848), for

That gives you:

```bash
mk start --no-kubernetes
```

Output:

```
minikube v1.24.0-beta.0 on Darwin 11.6 (arm64)
Automatically selected the docker driver
Starting minikube without Kubernetes minikube in cluster minikube
Pulling base image ...
Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=1988MB) ...
Done! minikube is ready without Kubernetes!
```

> ### Things to try without Kubernetes
>
> - "`minikube ssh`" to SSH into minikube's node.
> - "`minikube docker-env`" to build images by pointing to the docker inside minikube
> - "`minikube image`" to build images without docker

Answer (score 2):

Building off the earlier answer to use `eval $(minikube docker-env)` in order to load up Minikube's Docker environment, for an easier toggle, add the following function to your [shell rc file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example):

```
dockube() {
  if [[ $1 = 'which' ]]; then
    if [[ $MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD = 'minikube' ]]; then
      echo $MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD
    else
      echo 'system'
    fi
    return
  fi

  if [[ $MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD = 'minikube' ]]; then
    eval $(minikube docker-env -u)
    echo "now using system docker"
  else
    eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
    echo "now using minikube docker"
  fi
}
```

`dockube` without any argument will toggle between the system and Minikube Docker environment, and `dockube which` will return which one is in use.

Answer (score 1):

#### Short version

**Upload** to the Minikube repository:

```
minikube image load imageName
```

**Verify** the upload:

```
minikube image ls
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you could just run Kubernetes within Docker's virtual machine? There's native support for this with the more recent versions of [Docker Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)#Adoption)... You just need to enable that support.

- *https://www.docker.com/blog/kubernetes-is-now-available-in-docker-desktop-stable-channel/*
- *[Docker for Windows Desktop… Now With Kubernetes!](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-windows-desktop-now-kubernetes/)*

How I found this out:

While reading the documentation for [Helm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes#History), they give you a brief tutorial how to install Minikube.
That tutorial installs Minikube in a virtual machine that's different/separate from Docker.

So when it came time to install my Helm charts, I couldn't get Helm/Kubernetes to pull the images I had built using Docker. That's how I arrived here at this question.

So... if you can live with whatever version of Kubernetes comes with Docker Desktop, and you can live with it running in whatever VM Docker has, then maybe this solution is a bit easier than some of the others.

Disclaimer: I am not sure how switching between Windows/Linux containers would impact anything.

Comment: I think I also had to set the imagePullPolicies to IfNotPresent as well

Comment: The first link is (effectively) broken (it redirects to a generic page).

Answer (score 0):

1. setup: `minikube docker-env`
2. again build the same Docker image (using `minikube docker-env`)
3. change imagePullPolicy to **Never** in your deployment

Actually, your Minikube can't recognise your Docker daemon as it is ab independent service. You have to first set your Minikube-Docker environment use the below command to check:

```
 "eval $(minikube docker-env)"
```

If you run the below command, it will show where your Minikube instance looks for Docker.

```
cd ~
minikube docker-env
```

Output:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.37.192:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/home/ubuntu/.minikube/certs"
export MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD="minikube"

**# To point your shell to minikube's docker-daemon, run:**
# eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
```

You have to again build images once you set up the Minikube `docker-env`. Else, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative solution:

Let's say I already have the `Nginx` image locally.

```
docker save -o nginx.tar nginx:1.19.0-alpine
minikube ssh
docker load -i /path/to/nginx.tar
```

Now, you can create a Kubernetes deployment using the local docker image.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.19.0-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent  # Note: you can also user 'Never'
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Finally:

```
kubectl apply -f my-deployment.yml
```

Answer (score -1):

You can reuse the Docker shell, with `eval $(minikube docker-env)`. Alternatively, you can leverage `docker save | docker load` across the shells.

Answer (score -1):

I find this method from [ClickHouse Operator Build From Sources](https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-operator/blob/master/docs/operator_build_from_sources.md) and it helps and save my life!

```
docker save altinity/clickhouse-operator | (eval $(minikube docker-env) &&
docker load)
```

Answer (score -1):

In Minikube 1.20, `minikube cache add imagename:tag` is deprecated.

Instead, use `minikube image load imagename:tag`.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand, you have local images, maybe passed by a [USB flash drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive) and want to load it in Minikube?

Just load the image like:

```
minikube image load my-local-image:0.1
```

With this, in the Kubernetes [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) file, you can change the **imagePullPolicy** to **Never**, and it will be found, because you just loaded it in Minikube.

I had this problem, have done this, and it worked.

Comment: This copies the image from local to minikube. To note, of course a 20GB image on local will allocate other 20GB inside minikube, when loaded. In my case would be useful to understand why the image is being built on local rather than inside Minikube.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the answers are already great.
But one important thing I have faced is that if you are using BuildKit

> (DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1)

then the images created after executing the `eval $(minkube docker-env)` ***will not*** go to the Minikube Docker engine. ***Instead*** it will go to your Docker engine on local.

So remove any of the references if you are using below

> -mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2