# On Windows Setup, how can I get docker image from local machine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I could understand, different ways to access docker image from local machine to Minikube VM.

[(Kubernetes + Minikube) can't get docker image from local registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065342/kubernetes-minikube-cant-get-docker-image-from-local-registry)

All these examples are for Mac/Linux user.

I'm looking for an equivalent suggestion for Windows user.

What's windows equivalent to -> eval $(minikube docker-env)

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this?

Answer (score 20):

I found relatively easy way to point docker client(docker-machine) to minikube’s docker environment by running below commands in PowerShell ->

PS C:\Users\ABC> minikube docker-env

PS C:\Users\ABC> minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression

Comment: I tried the same command from powershell. It didn't work for me.                          PS C:\tools\cloud> minikube docker-env
$Env:DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = "1"
$Env:DOCKER_HOST = "tcp://172.27.61.204:2376"
$Env:DOCKER_CERT_PATH = "C:\Users\sswain\.minikube\certs"
$Env:DOCKER_API_VERSION = "1.35"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# & minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression
PS C:\tools\cloud> & minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression

Comment: minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression seems to work only in PowerShell. In other terminals one needs to read the last line returned by minikube docker-env. For example, in IntelliJ it is @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env') DO @%i   Have to do this in any new terminal/session always before building the docker image.

Answer (score 4):

You can use below command in the command prompt,

```
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env') DO @%i
```

In fact when you run the command `minikube docker-env` it will instruct you how to connect,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like manvedra said ,those steps worked for me too. In a powershell command prompt and run the following commands:

`minikube start`, to start minikube cluster.

`minikube docker-env`, it will configure some environment variables and at bottom it will show the last command to be run.

`minikube -p minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression` , last step.

Done.

Comment: I'm a windows user and I'm getting this error when i try to build my image after running above commands       `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker build -t dhruv/posts:0.0.1 .`
`unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: CreateFile C:\Windows\System32\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Hi @SherryJain could please check if the Dockerfile existis in the current directory where you are running the docker build command. By your messange I think that its try find dockerfile inside C:\WINDOWS\system32. You should be at the directory where Dockerfile are or specify another path with -f like: docker build -t dhruv/posts:0.0.1 . -f <path to your dockerfile>

Answer (score 0):

Same error and this solution doesn't work for me.

I found this solution [here](https://learnk8s.io/blog/installing-docker-and-kubernetes-on-windows).

You should install docker separate way:

1. Download choco and with it help
2. Install docker-desktop
3. Restart entire your machine(don't forgive do it!)
4. Now you can do whatever you want to do with docker from command line

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party but you can do this on Windows:

minikube cache add alpine:latest

which gave me message that it is deprecated.

So finally use this:- minikube image load imagename

where imagename is docker daemons image name

Ref: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/image/#minikube-image-load

Answer (score 0):

These are the 3 commands basically you have to run -

> minikube start
> minikube docker-env
> & minikube -p minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please open windows powershell as mentioned in above answers, execute minikube docker-env.

--> result of the output , note down last line and execute it to point to docker instance inside k8s. I found below command, which is working for me.

minikube -p minikube docker-env --shell powershell | Invoke-Expression

Answer (score -1):

> What's windows equivalent to -> eval $(minikube docker-env)

either `docker-machine env my-default`

or

`@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env YOURMACHINENAME') DO @%i`

Comment: Thanks, tried both commands, they didn't product any error although localhost docker cli, still pointing to its default docker daemon. My expectation is, post successful execution of above commands, docker-cli should point to minikube docker daemon. What else missing?

Comment: im not sure what are you trying to do.. what you mean by  **docker-cli should point to minikube docker daemon** ..?

Comment: I've a windows machine, use Docker Toolbox for creating Docker images etc. On the same machine, I've also installed Minikube. Both Minikube & Docker Toolbox, come with its own default Docker daemon. I want to point docker client of my machine, to Minikube docker daemon. This way, need not to unnecessarily push & pull imaged from local docker repo.