# Kubernetes fails to run a docker image build locally

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to run a docker image that I have build locally with Kubernetes.

Here is my command line:

```
kubectl run myImage --image=myImage --port 3030 --image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent
```

I have seen many peoples saying that we need to add the `--image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent` flag so Kubernetes can look for the image locally instead of Docker Hub, but I still get this error (from the Minikube dashboard on the pod, the service and the deployment).

> Failed to pull image "myImage": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for myImage, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

But it looks like there is another issue here, I also tried `--image-pull-policy=Never` and it doesn't work either.

Any idea?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `image` is not available in `minikube`.

Minikube uses separate `docker daemon`. That's why, even though the image exists in your machine, it is still missing inside minikube.

First, send the image to minikube by,

```
docker save myImage | (eval $(minikube docker-env) && docker load)
```

This command will save the image as tar archive, then loads the image in minikube by itself.

Next, use the image in your deployment with `image-pull-policy` set to `IfNotPresent`

```
kubectl run myImage --image=myImage --port 3030 --image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent
```

Comment: what happens in case on normal kubernetes cluster? How do i locate which docker daemon is my cluster using?

Comment: @AvikAggarwal, every node of kubernetes cluster has a docker daemon running.

Comment: Please tell what Windows users should do because eval does not works in windows

Comment: @SherryJain, can you try this answer and see if it works? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61098992/4628962

Answer (score 2):

The image you created in the docker won't be available in the Minikube because Minikube have it's own docker daemon and it checks for the docker images there and DockerHub.

Follow the below steps to access the Minikube Docker daemon, build and deploy the docker image:

1. use the minikube `docker-env command` that outputs environment variables needed to point the local Docker daemon to the minikube internal Docker registry.

> minikube docker-env export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=”1" export
> DOCKER_HOST=”tcp://172.17.0.2:2376" export
> DOCKER_CERT_PATH=”/home/user/.minikube/certs” export
> MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD=”minikube”

#To point your shell to minikube’s docker-daemon,  # run:  eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)

2. To apply these variables,

   > eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
3. Now need to build the image once again, so that it’s installed in the minikube registry, instead of the local one:

   > docker build . -t forketyfork/hello-world

forketyfork/hello-world is the name of the docker image.

4. Deploy the image to kubernetes or Minkube via the yaml [configuartion file.](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/kube-deploy/)

   > kubectl create -f helloworld.yml

helloworld.yml is the name of the yml/yaml file.

5. Now `kubectl get pods` to get the status of the pods

For further reference, https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-run-locally-built-docker-images-in-kubernetes-b28fbc32cc1d

Answer (score 1):

A really simple solution would be

`minikube image load --daemon myImageName -p myProfileName`

User the `-p` flag if you are using a profile otherwise it can be skipped

`minikube image ls -p myProfileName`

Reference:
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/#7-loading-directly-to-in-cluster-container-runtime