# Kubernetes Minikube Docker trying and failing to pull image

Tags: image, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have a docker image called docker-hello-world - all it does is print Hello World to the log using the JRE.  When tested it works fine.

Then, I import an image into Kubernetes Docker and run – still no issues.

```
docker images -a
REPOSITORY                                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker-hello-world                                     latest              9a161d166742        20 hours ago        83.17 MB
```

3. When I try and deploy into Kubernetes with `kubectl run docker-hello-world --image=docker-hello-world:latest`  something goes wrong here – I tried the image id as well but I can’t understand why it can’t find the image.

It says deployment created.

```
kubectl get deployments
NAME                 DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
docker-hello-world   1         1                1                   0           24s

kubectl get pods
NAME                                                READY     STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
docker-hello-world-67c745cff4-sv77d   0/1       ErrImagePull   0          43s
```

Logs:

```
kubectl logs docker-hello-world-67c745cff4-sv77d
Error from server (BadRequest): container "docker-hello-world" in pod "docker-hello-world-67c745cff4-sv77d" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

Im not sure why it can’t find the image.

But if I do from within Minikube:

```
docker build -t dummy:v1 ~/eclipse-workspace/HelloWorld/bin/
```

(I don’t really want do generate the image again)

```
docker images
REPOSITORY                                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
dummy                                                  v1                  beae3bfd2327        32 seconds ago      83.17 MB

kubectl run --image=dummy:v1 dummy
deployment "dummy” created

kubectl get deployments
NAME           DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
dummy          1                1           1                   0           11s

kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
dummy-8496dd7d84-t4h66          0/1       Completed   4          1m

kubectl logs dummy-8496dd7d84-t4h66
Hello, World
```

It seems to work ok

Comment: Did the IP address of the machine change after you have installed minibuke? Was it working first time and started failing after IP change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use local docker images in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-to-use-local-docker-images-in-kubernetes)

Answer (score 13):

The version tag of the image `docker-hello-world:latest` is `latest`, which indicates the default `ImagePullPolicy` is `Always` (see `pkg/apis/core/v1/defaults.go` for v1.9.x and after). It will try to pull image from the hub and not use the image already present.

One option is set a specific tag rather than `latest`.