# Deploying a docker-compose app on Kubernetes on Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I am trying to follow the instructions at https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/kubernetes/#use-docker-commands for running a docker-compose.yml file against kubernetes on Docker for Windows.

I am using the Edge version of Docker for Windows -- 18.03.0-ce-rc4 -- and I have kubernetes enabled.

I am using the example docker-compose app at https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-3-define-services-in-a-compose-file, i.e.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
  redis:
    image: redis
```

This example works fine with `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`

But following the documentation linked above for `docker stack`, I get the following:

```
PS C:\dev\projects\python\kubetest> docker stack deploy --compose-file .\docker-compose.yml mystack
Ignoring unsupported options: build

Stack mystack was created
Waiting for the stack to be stable and running...
 - Service redis has one container running
PS C:\dev\projects\python\kubetest> kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP     5d
redis        ClusterIP   None         <none>        55555/TCP   8s
```

Note that it doesn't create the web service, along with that "ignoring unsupported options: build" error

I also tried using the sample docker-compose.yml file in that documentation linked above, and it didn't work, either, with a totally different error.

In short, by following the documentation, I'm unable to get anything deployed to kubernetes on Docker for Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the lack of support for a `build` there would be no `image` to run for the `web` service containers.

Compose can manage the build for you on a single Docker host. As Swarm and Kubernetes are normally run across multiple nodes, an `image` should reference a registry available on the network so all nodes can access the same image.

[Dockers `stack deploy` example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/#create-the-example-application) includes a step to [setup a private registry](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/#set-up-a-docker-registry) and use that for source of the image:

```
services:
  web:
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/stackdemo
```

#### Workaround

In this instance, it *might* be possible to get away with building the image manually and referencing that image name due to everything running under the one Docker instance, it depends on how Kubernetes is setup.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: me/web
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
  redis:
    image: redis
```

Build the image externally

```
docker-compose build web
```

or directly with `docker`:

```
docker build -t me/web .
```

Comment: Thank you! I have now documented all the steps I needed to take to get this successfully working at https://marcesher.com/2018/03/28/docker-for-windows-deploying-a-docker-compose-app-to-local-kubernetes/

Answer (score 3):

there is a project:

> https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose

called **Docker Kompose** that helps users who already have docker-compose files to deploy their applications on Kubernetes as easy as possible by automatically converting their existing docker-compose file into many yaml files.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when following the official instruction.

To bypass this issue, I chose using `kubectl` for deploying docker images to local k8s instead of using `docker stack` (seems the root cause might be the `--orchestrator kubernetes` flag, it doesn't work).

Here are the steps:

1. **Using the Kubernetes' docker registry per terminal (important)**:

   run `& minikube docker-env | iex` under Windows Powershell (`iex` is the alias of `Invoke-Expression`)

   or

   run `eval $(minikube docker-env)` under bash environment.

   After that, run `docker image ls`, make sure your docker registry is set to Kubernetes's env. (You should see some default images under 'k8s.gcr.io' domain.)

   You may need to do this in **every** terminal if multiple terminals are opened.
2. **Rebuild your docker image**:

   run `docker-compose -f /path/to/your/docker-compose.yml build`

   Your image should appear in K8s's local registry.
3. **Run your image with 'kubectl'**:

   run `kubectl run hello-world --image=myimage --image-pull-policy=Never`

#### References:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48999680/4989702

Answer (score 0):

Though it might be possible to deploy docker compose yamls in kubernetes as suggested. It is better to create the right kubernetes yamls to deploy on your specific cluster.

There are some tools out there which can make your life simple.

One such tool is Move2Kube (https://github.com/konveyor/move2kube). You can do

```
move2kube translate -s <folder containing the dockerfiles>
```

It can create the relevant deployments, services, ingress, etc that will be required to deploy your application.