# 127.0.0.1:5000: getsockopt: connection refused in Minikube

Tags: docker, minikube

Using minikube and docker on my local Ubuntu workstation I get the following error in the Minikube web UI:

```
Failed to pull image "localhost:5000/samples/myserver:snapshot-180717-213718-0199": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get http://localhost:5000/v2/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: getsockopt: connection refused
```

after I have created the below deployment config with:

```
kubectl apply -f hello-world-deployment.yaml
```

**hello-world-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-world
        image: localhost:5000/samples/myserver:snapshot-180717-213718-0199
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        env:
        - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
          value: dns
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

And output from docker images:

```
REPOSITORY                                 TAG                           IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
samples/myserver                           latest                        aa0a1388cd88        About an hour ago   435MB
samples/myserver                           snapshot-180717-213718-0199   aa0a1388cd88        About an hour ago   435MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy-amd64                v1.10.0                       bfc21aadc7d3        3 months ago        97MB
```

Based on this guide:
[How to use local docker images with Minikube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-to-use-local-docker-images-with-minikube)

I have also run:

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

and based on this:

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/624

I have added:

```
    "InsecureRegistry": [
        "localhost:5000",
        "127.0.0.1:5000"
    ],
```

to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

Any suggestion on what I missing to get the image pull to work in minikube?

I have followed the steps in the below answer but when I get to this step:

```
$ kubectl port-forward --namespace kube-system $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | grep kube-registry-v0 | awk '{print $1;}') 5000:5000
```

it just hangs like this:

```
$ kubectl port-forward --namespace kube-system $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | grep kube-registry-v0 | awk '{print $1;}') 5000:5000
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:5000 -> 5000
Forwarding from [::1]:5000 -> 5000
```

and I get the same error in minikube dashboard after I create my deploymentconfig.

Based on answer from **BMitch** I have now tried to create a local docker repository and push an image to it with:

```
$ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart always --name registry registry:2
$ docker pull ubuntu
$ docker tag ubuntu localhost:5000/ubuntu:v1
$ docker push localhost:5000/ubuntu:v1
```

Next when I do docker images I get:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                      TAG                           IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu                                          latest                        74f8760a2a8b        4 days ago          82.4MB
localhost:5000/ubuntu                           v1                            74f8760a2a8b        4 days ago          82.4MB
```

I have then updated my deploymentconfig **hello-world-deployment.yaml** to:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-world
        image: localhost:5000/ubuntu:v1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        env:
        - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
          value: dns
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

and

```
kubectl create -f hello-world-deployment.yaml
```

But in Minikube I still get similar error:

```
 Failed to pull image "localhost:5000/ubuntu:v1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get http://localhost:5000/v2/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: getsockopt: connection refused
```

So seems Minikube is not allowed to see the local registry I just created?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you’re facing a problem with **localhost on your computer** and **localhost** used within the context **of minikube VM**.
To have registry working, you have to set an additional port forwarding.

If your [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/) installation is currently broken due to a lot of attempts to fix registry problems, 
I would suggest restarting minikube environment:

```
minikube stop && minikube delete && rm -fr $HOME/.minikube &&  minikube start
```

Next, get kube registry yaml file:

```
curl -O https://gist.githubusercontent.com/coco98/b750b3debc6d517308596c248daf3bb1/raw/6efc11eb8c2dce167ba0a5e557833cc4ff38fa7c/kube-registry.yaml
```

Then, apply it on minikube:

```
kubectl create -f kube-registry.yaml
```

Test if registry inside minikube VM works:

```
minikube ssh && curl localhost:5000
```

On Ubuntu, forward ports to reach registry at port 5000:

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace kube-system $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | grep kube-registry-v0 | awk '{print $1;}') 5000:5000
```

If you would like to share your private registry from your machine, you may be interested in [sharing local registry for minikube](https://blog.hasura.io/sharing-a-local-registry-for-minikube-37c7240d0615) blog entry.

Comment: I have followed the steps above but I still get the same error when specifying the path to the docker image in my deploymentconfig:   localhost:5000/samples/myserver:snapshot-180717-213718-0199

Comment: the yaml file you mentioned is outdated, i got it to working state and published here, https://gist.github.com/dinukasal/302300d6d7c48885f574c3fae65eeefc

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifying the image source as the local registry server, you'll need to run a registry server there, and push your images to it.

You can self host a registry server with multiple 3rd party options, or run this one that is packaged inside a docker container: https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/

This only works on a single node environment unless you setup TLS keys, trust the CA, or tell all other nodes of the additional insecure registry.

You can also specify the imagePullPolicy as Never.

---

Both of these solutions were already in your linked question and I'm not seeing any evidence of you trying either in this question. Without showing how you tried those steps and experienced a different problem, this question should probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: But I already have installed docker locally and can see my local images with 'docker images' why can't I just use my local docker installation as "registry"/"repository"? Also from what I understand Minikube only supports a single node cluster so that part should be covered.

Comment: @u123 If you just want to run locally built images, then the answer probably isn't kubernetes. You can do that just fine with docker. If you want to discuss the design of the kubernetes architecture, I'm probably the wrong person to ask, I'm just here to try to solve the problem you're having.

Comment: No I would like to run it inside minikube/kubernetes to understand that setup, I am just confused why I need to create a local registry when I thought I already had that by default when installing docker. But apparently that this something else.

Comment: @u123 docker engine != docker registry server. You don't need to host your images on localhost, could have them in the cloud (docker hub) or some other on premises server, so docker doesn't ship with one on the engine. Since it only takes 30 seconds to start, I'm not sure why this is such an issue.

Comment: Well not really an issue, just trying to understand the setup. I have now created a local registry and pushed an image to it as you suggested but seems minikube is still not allowed to pull the image. I have updated my original post with an example.

Comment: Did you create the registry inside the minikube vm?

Comment: I have tried to create the registry on my host machine - did not work - and inside minikube where i created it by first running 'minikube ssh' and then run the above commands. That gives the same error. Btw: minikube version: v0.28.1 so maybe its not supported in this version?

Answer (score 0):

it is unclear from your question how many nodes do you have?

**If you have more than one, your problem is in your deployment with replicas: 1.**

If not, please ignore this answer.

You don't know where and what that replica will be. So if you don't have docker local registry on all of your nodes, and you got unlucky that kubernetes is trying to use some node without docker registry, you will end up with that error.

Same thing happened to me, same error `connection refused` because deployment went to node without local docker registry.

As I am typing this, I think this can be resolved with ingress.
You do registry as deployment, add service, add volume for images and put it to ingress.

Little more of work but at least all your nodes will be sync (all of your pods sorry).