# Use local docker image with minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, linux-mint, minikube

I was following this URL: [How to use local docker images with Minikube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-to-use-local-docker-images-with-minikube)
I couldn't add a comment, so thought of putting my question here:

On my laptop, I have Linux Mint OS. Details as below:

```
Mint version 19, 
Code name : Tara,
PackageBase : Ubuntu Bionic
Cinnamon (64-bit)
```

As per one the answer on the above-referenced link:

1. I started minikube and checked pods and deployments

> ```
> xxxxxxxxx:~$ pwd
> /home/sj
>
> xxxxxxxxxx:~$ minikube start
> xxxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl get pods
> xxxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl get deployments
> ```

I ran command docker images

```
xxxxxxxxx:~$ docker images

REPOSITORY                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<username>/spring-docker-01   latest              e10f88e1308d        6 days ago          640MB
openjdk                           8                   81f83aac57d6        4 weeks ago         624MB
mysql                             5.7                 563a026a1511        4 weeks ago         372MB
```

2. I ran below command:

> eval $(minikube docker-env)

3. Now when I check docker images, looks like as the [README](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/0c616a6b42b28a1aab8397f5a9061f8ebbd9f3d9/README.md#reusing-the-docker-daemon) describes, it reuses the Docker daemon from Minikube with eval $(minikube docker-env).

   xxxxxxxxxxxxx:~$ docker images

> ```
> REPOSITORY                                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
> nginx                                      alpine              33c5c6e11024        9 days ago          17.7MB
> k8s.gcr.io/coredns                         1.2.2               367cdc8433a4        5 weeks ago         39.2MB
> k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64      v1.10.0             0dab2435c100        5 weeks ago         122MB
> k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy-amd64                v1.10.0             bfc21aadc7d3        6 months ago        97MB
> k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager-amd64   v1.10.0             ad86dbed1555        6 months ago        148MB
> k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver-amd64            v1.10.0             af20925d51a3        6 months ago        225MB
> k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler-amd64            v1.10.0             704ba848e69a        6 months ago        50.4MB
> k8s.gcr.io/etcd-amd64                      3.1.12              52920ad46f5b        6 months ago        193MB
> k8s.gcr.io/kube-addon-manager              v8.6                9c16409588eb        7 months ago        78.4MB
> k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64     1.14.8              c2ce1ffb51ed        9 months ago        41MB
> k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64           1.14.8              6f7f2dc7fab5        9 months ago        42.2MB
> k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64          1.14.8              80cc5ea4b547        9 months ago        50.5MB
> k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64                     3.1                 da86e6ba6ca1        9 months ago        742kB
> gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner    v1.8.1              4689081edb10        11 months ago       80.8MB
> k8s.gcr.io/echoserver                      1.4                 a90209bb39e3        2 years ago         140MB
> ```

*Note: if noticed docker images command pulled different images before and after step 2.*

4. As I didn't see the image that I wanted to put on minikube, I pulled it from my docker hub.

> ```
> xxxxxxxxxxxxx:~$ docker pull <username>/spring-docker-01
> Using default tag: latest
> latest: Pulling from <username>/spring-docker-01
> 05d1a5232b46: Pull complete 
> 5cee356eda6b: Pull complete 
> 89d3385f0fd3: Pull complete 
> 80ae6b477848: Pull complete 
> 40624ba8b77e: Pull complete 
> 8081dc39373d: Pull complete 
> 8a4b3841871b: Pull complete 
> b919b8fd1620: Pull complete 
> 2760538fe600: Pull complete 
> 48e4bd518143: Pull complete 
> Digest: sha256:277e8f7cfffdfe782df86eb0cd0663823efc3f17bb5d4c164a149e6a59865e11
> Status: Downloaded newer image for <username>/spring-docker-01:latest
> ```

5. Verified if I can see that image using "docker images" command.

> ```
> xxxxxxxxxxxxx:~$ docker images
> REPOSITORY                                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
> <username>/spring-docker-01            latest              e10f88e1308d        6 days ago          640MB
> nginx                                      alpine              33c5c6e11024        10 days ago         17.7MB
> ```

6. Then I tried to build image as stated in referenced link step.

> ```
> xxxxxxxxxx:~$ docker build -t <username>/spring-docker-01 .
> unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/sj/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
> ```

**As the error states that dockerfile doesn't exist at the location, I am not sure where exactly I can see dockerfile for the image I had pulled from docker hub.**

Looks like I have to go to the location where the image has been pulled and from that location, I need to run the above-mentioned command. Please correct me wrong.

Below are the steps, I will be doing after I fix the above-mentioned issue.

```
# Run in minikube
kubectl run hello-foo --image=myImage --image-pull-policy=Never

# Check that it's running
kubectl get pods
```

---

UPDATE-1

There is mistake in above steps.
Step 6 is not needed. Image has already been pulled from docker hub, so no need of `docker build` command.

With that, I went ahead and followed instructions as mentioned by @aurelius in response.

```
xxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl run sdk-02 --image=<username>/spring-docker-01:latest --image-pull-policy=Never
kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1beta1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl create instead.
deployment.apps/sdk-02 created
```

Checked pods and deployments

```
xxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl get pods
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
sdk-02-b6db97984-2znlt       1/1     Running   0          27s
xxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl get deployments
NAME        DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
sdk-02      1         1         1            1           35s
```

Then exposed deployment on port 8084 as I was using other ports like 8080 thru 8083

```
xxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl expose deployment sdk-02 --type=NodePort --port=8084
service/sdk-02 exposed
```

Then verified if service has been started, checked if no issue on kubernetes dashboard and then checked the url

```
xxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          7h
sdk-02       NodePort       10.100.125.120   <none>        8084:30362/TCP   13s

xxxxxxxxx:~$ minikube service sdk-02 --url
http://192.168.99.101:30362
```

When I tried to open URL: http://192.168.99.101:30362 in browser I got message:

```
This site can’t be reached
192.168.99.101 refused to connect.
Search Google for 192 168 101 30362
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

**So the question : Is there any issue with steps performed?**

---

UPDATE-2

The issue was with below step:

```
xxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl expose deployment sdk-02 --type=NodePort --port=8084
    service/sdk-02 exposed
```

Upon checking Dockerfile of my image : `<username>/spring-docker-01:latest` I was exposing it to 8083 something like `EXPOSE 8083`
May be that was causing issue. 
So I went ahead and changed expose command:

```
xxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl expose deployment sdk-02 --type=NodePort --port=8083
service/sdk-02 exposed
```

And then it started working.

*If anyone has something to add to this, please feel free.*

**However I am still not sure where exactly I can see dockerfile for the image I had pulled from docker hub.**

Comment: You should run the command `docker build -t shivnilesh1109/spring-docker-01 .` in the directory which the Dockerfile in.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT That's what my question was. Let me rephrase it : I have pulled a image "myImage" from my docker hub using command `docker pull username/myImage` . How to find out location where that image is stored on my location machine?

Comment: I have updated description with more details **UPDATE-1** Please have a look at all steps carefully and let me know if I am making any mistake there.

Comment: Got this working. However only 1 question remains. Please check **UPDATE-2**

Answer (score 1):

The `docker build` does not know what you mean by your [command](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/edge/engine/reference/commandline/build/#usage), because flag -t requires specific format:

> --tag , -t        Name and optionally a tag in the ‘**name:tag**’ format

`xxxxxxxxxx:~/Downloads$ docker build -t shivnilesh1109/spring-docker-01 .`

So the proper command here should be:

```
docker build -t shivnilesh1109/spring-docker-01:v1(1) .(2)
```

(1) desired name of your container:tag
(2) directory in which your dockerfile is.

After you proceed to minikube deployment, it will be enough just to  run:
`kubectl run *desired name of deployment/pod* --image=*name of the container with tag* --image-pull-policy=Never`

If this would not fix your issue, try adding the path to Dockerfile manually. I've tested this on my machine and error stopped after using proper tagging of the image and tested this also with full path to Dockerfile otherwise I had the same error as you.

Comment: I have problem with (2) from your response. Let me rephrase it : I have pulled a image "myImage" from my docker hub using command `docker pull username/myImage` . How to find out location where that image is stored on my location machine?

Comment: I have updated description with more details **UPDATE-1** Please have a look at all steps carefully and let me know if I am making any mistake there.

Answer (score 1):

For you UPDATE-2 question, also to help you to understand the port exposed in the Dockerfile and in the command `kubectl expose`.

**Dockerfile:**

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
>   functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
>   image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
>   intended to be published.

For more details, see [EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose).

**Kubectl expose:**

> **--port**: The port that the service should serve on. Copied from the resource being exposed, if unspecified
>
> **--target-port**: Name or number for the port on the container that the service should direct traffic to. Optional.

For more details, see [kubectl expose](https://www.mankier.com/1/kubectl-expose).

So I think you should add the parameters `--target-port` with the port that you exposed in the Dockerfile. And then the port mapping will be correct.

Comment: _Dokerfile_  has `EXPOSE 8083` then _kubectl expose_  I changed command with `--port 8084 --target-port 8083`  and it worked. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a Dockerfile with this content:

```
FROM shivnilesh1109/spring-docker-01
```

Then run:

```
docker build -t my-spring-docker-01 .
```

Comment: command `FROM shivnilesh1109/spring-docker-01` didn't work. Not sure if I understood your response correctly.

Comment: That's not a command. You need to create a file named `Dockerfile` and inside that file you need to add `FROM shivnilesh1109/spring-docker-01`

Comment: The basic problem what I am facing still remains the same.  I have pulled a image "myImage" from my docker hub using command `docker pull username/myImage` . In order to create dockerfile, first I need to find out location where that image is stored on my location machine. I am having problem with that.

Comment: I even tried to go to docker root directory: `xxxxxxxxxx:/var/lib/docker# ls
**builder  buildkit  containerd  containers  image  network  overlay2  plugins  runtimes  swarm  tmp  trust  volumes**` Not sure where exactly that pulled image gets stored.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need the files on your local docker image?

Comment: I am confused now with that question of yours. All I am trying to do is use one of the local image with minikube. I am trying exact same steps as mentioned in the issue description. Am I doing some mistake in any of those steps?

Comment: Got this working. However only 1 question remains. Please check **UPDATE-2**

Answer (score 0):

try adding your local docker image to minikube's cache , like so :

```
minikube cache add docker-image-name:latesttag
```

then set  `imagePullPolicy:Never` in the yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Dockerfile is listed in `.dockerignore`, if so - comment it out