# How do I set the imagePullPolicy with Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am new to Kubernetes.  I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/#quickstart) that instructs me on how to use minikube to setup a local service.  I was able to get things running with the `$ kubectl run hello-minikube --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.10 --port=8080` service from the tutorial. Huzzah!

Now I want to run a server with a *locally tagged-and-built* Docker image.  According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-to-use-local-docker-images-with-minikube) all I need to do is tell my computer to use the minikube docker daemon, build my image, and set the `imagePullPolicy` to never.

How and where do I set the `imagePullPolicy` with `minikube`?  I've googled around and while there's plenty of results, my "babe in the woods" status with K8 leads to information overload. (i.e. the simpler your answer the better)

Comment: Is your host OS for minikube windows or linux?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh MacOS -- which I think means things are running behind the scenes in a linux VM?

Comment: Right, sorry asked because I like to test stuff out before I set people on the wrong route and I don't have MacOS, so hopefully someone else can help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to edit your [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) (`kubectl run` creates a deployment). The spec would look something like this:

```
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: hello-minikube
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: hello-minikube
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.10 <-- change to the right image
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent <-- change to Always
        name: hello-minikube
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

Edit with:

```
$ kubectl edit deployment hello-minikube
```

Comment: Ah, got it. I'd seen the `deployment` used in the tutorial but didn't understand it.  You answered both my original question, and one I didn't realize I had.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the key for `kubectl run command`:

```
--image-pull-policy Never
```