# What's the benefit of not using ImagePullPolicy set to Always?

Tags: kubernetes

In the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images) it mentions that the caching semantic of using `ImagePullPolicy: Always` makes the ImagePullPolicy quite efficient. What reasons would I want to choose a different ImagePullPolicy?

Comment: Possible reason: To be even more efficient then just quite :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't much of a disadvantage to `ImagePullPolicy: Always`, but having the control means that:

- if you have an underlying image provider that doesn't provide caching (ie you're not using Docker), you have control to make sure that it's not called every time the kubelet wants the image
- even with Docker caching, it's still going to be slightly faster to not attempt to pull the image every time. If you know that you never re-use a tag (which is recommended) or you're explicitly specifying the image digest then there's no benefit to `ImagePullPolicy: Always`
- if you have an installation where you're pulling the image onto the node using a separate mechanism, you may want it to not attempt an automatic fetch if something goes wrong and the image doesn't exist.

Note that in fiunchinho's answer it mentions that you can use it to keep various replicas of an application in sync. This would be dangerous as images are pulled per node, so you could end up with different versions of the application running on different nodes.

Answer (score 6):

It heavily depends on your versioning/tagging strategy.

When new replicas of your application are created (because your app has scaled up, or a pod has died and it's been replaced by a new pod), if you use `ImagePullPolicy: Always` and you have pushed a different version of your application using the same tag (like people do when using `latest`), the new created replicas might run a totally different version of the application than the rest of the replicas, leading to an inconsistent behavior.

You also may want to use a different value than `Always` when [on a development environment like minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42564211/563072).