# setting image pull policy using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Following the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-to-use-local-docker-images-with-minikube), I am trying to pull a image that I created locally with docker while creating deployment with **kubectl**. I am looking for something like this,

`kubectl create deployment first-k8s-deploy --image="laxman/nodejs/express-app" --image-pull-policy="never"`

Looking into `kubectl create deployment --help` doesn't provide any `--image-pull-policy` option.

Is there any global config to set imagePullPolicy and how can I set this flag for some specific deployments only?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might have gone past what can be done with the command line. See [Creating a Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment) for how to specify a deployment in a yaml file.

The `imagePullPolicy` is part of the [Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#container-v1-core) definition.

You can get the yaml for any `kubectl` command by adding `-o yaml --dry-run` to the command. Using your example deployment:

```
kubectl create deployment first-k8s-deploy \
  --image="laxman/nodejs/express-app" \
  -o yaml \
  --dry-run
```

Gives you:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: first-k8s-deploy
  name: first-k8s-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: first-k8s-deploy
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: first-k8s-deploy
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: laxman/nodejs/express-app
        name: express-app
        resources: {}
```

Then add the `imagePullPolicy` property into a container in the list:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: laxman/nodejs/express-app
        name: express-app
        resources: {}
        imagePullPolicy: Never
```

The yaml file you create can then be deployed with the following command

`kubectl apply -f <filename>`

Comment: thanks @Matt, but don't you think if something that can be achieved with yaml file must also have support with the cli ?

Comment: The full data model is way too complex to represent as cli options.

Comment: you must be careful, to apply the deploment at the end. if you apply the deployment and then add the setting  ,it will have a downside: first time the container is created using the old image ( imagepullpolicy off),then a new container is created,with the new image.

Answer (score 8):

It's possible to specify `--image-pull-policy` for a single `pod` using the cli.

So you can create and run a `pod` using:

`kubectl run PODNAME --image='laxman/nodejs/express-app' --image-pull-policy='Never'`

You can see other examples and detailed explanation by doing `kubectl run --help` and documentation is available [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run).

Like I said this applied to `pods` if you add option `--generator=deployment/v1beta1` it will create a Deployment.
This is going to be **Deprecated starting from Kubernetes 1.18** [pull request was approved and merged](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/87077).

Comment: With my kubectl version (v1.19.7) never needs to be in capitals `--image-pull-policy='Never'`