# Run a locally made container on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile

On an on-premise Kubernetes Cluster, how to use locally build images in the Kubernetes deployment manifest without having it uploaded to a Docker Registry (like Docker Hub)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use local docker images with Minikube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-to-use-local-docker-images-with-minikube)

Comment: I believe it doesn't @omricoco, as I'm not using minikube, and the commands in that answer seems to work around it.

Answer (score 3):

Except for some very limited developer-oriented setups (like Minikube or Kind), a Docker registry of some form is basically required to run applications on Kubernetes.

The only two ways to get a Docker image on to a system are by running a registry, or to `docker load` it.  The `docker load` path involves transferring a (possibly large) image tar file to *every* node in the cluster, and running the `load` command there.  When you update the application image, you'll have to repeat this step; and you generally want to avoid the `latest` image tag and similar fixed strings so that the Kubernetes deployment mechanism can correctly update things, so you'll have to repeat this for each version anything in the cluster might still be using.  The mechanics of setting up some place to store the image, copying it to every node in the cluster, running `docker load` everywhere, *etc.* aren't actually any easier than just running a Docker registry server yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You already have an on-prem machine. All you need to do is just do a docker build from your dockerfile, do a suitable docker tag and create the manifest.

Kubernetes doesn't directly pull from the registry. First it searches for the image on local storage and then docker registry.

1. Pull latest nginx image

   **docker pull nginx**

   **docker tag nginx:latest test:test8970**
2. Create a deployment
   `kubectl run test --image=test:test8970`
   It won't go to docker registry to pull the image. It will bring up the pod instantly.
   [image]
3. And if **image is not present on local machine** it will try to pull from docker registry and fail with **ErrImagePull** error.
   [image]
4. Also if you change the **imagePullPolicy: Never**. It will never look for the registry to pull the image and will fail if image is not found with error **ErrImageNeverPull**.
   [image]

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: test
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: test
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: test:test8070
        name: test
        imagePullPolicy: Never
```

Comment: This seems right. I'll give it a try and post the results. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I tried the same yesterday for you. It seemed to be working fine. I hope it works for you as well. I had to spin up a minikube cluster backed by hypervkit on MacOS with 1.16 version of k8s.

Comment: It might work with minikube but it does not work within a real K8s cluster.