# Kubernetes pod status ImagePullBackOff

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to create a pod based on a container image from local machine not from public registry. I am retrieving the status of pod as ImagePullBackoff
Docker file

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3
RUN pip install -q keras==2.3.1
RUN pip install pillow
RUN mkdir -p /app/src
WORKDIR /app/src
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 31700
CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

To build the docker image

```
docker build -t tensor-keras .
```

To create a pod without using yaml file

```
kubectl run server --image=tensor-keras:latest
```

Yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: server
 labels: 
    app: server
spec:
 containers:
  - name:  tensor-keras
    image: tensor-keras:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 31700
```

I am retreiving the status of the pod as

```
  NAME          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
  server         0/1   ImagePullBackOff      0        27m
```

Help is highly appreciated thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Kubernetes will try to pull your image from a remote container repository. In your case, your image name is not prefixed by a container repository url, so it uses default one, most of the time it is set to Docker Hub.

What is the value of the  `imagePullPolicy` field? For you use-case it should be set to `Never` to use local image.
Which tool are you using to run your Kubernetes instance?

- For example, with minikube, procedure to use a local image is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42564211/2784039
- With kind, you should use command `kind load docker-image <tensor-keras:latest>` o load the image inside your cluser
- With k3s, using local image should work out of the box, if `imagePullPolicy` is set to  `Never`

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful help @fjammes, I am not using minikube, or k3s I am using k8s. I will try your solultion and will update you asap

Comment: Hi @fjammes, I tried this solution , now the status is crashloopbackoff.

Comment: @abaairdavis As the underlying issue of accessing an image was resolved, please consider creating another question with information specific to the `Crashloopbackoff` state of your `Pod` like `$ kubectl describe pod server`, `$ kubectl logs server`.

Comment: Hi, thanks @DawidKruk for your wonderful help. I have solved the issue, the issue was of the docker image file