# Using a local image on minikube

Tags: docker, minikube

I'm trying to use a local image on minikube.  In order to build the image I run the following command

```
docker build -t goserver:1.0.0 .
```

My yaml file for minikube contains the following

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: goserver
  namespace: golang-ns
  labels:
    app: goserver
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: goserver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: goserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: goserver
        image: goserver:1.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

However when I try `kubectl apply -f ./k8s.yaml, I get the following error

```
Container image "goserver:1.0.0" is not present with pull policy of Never
Error: ErrImageNeverPull
```

I did a bit of searching and I found the following

[How to use local docker images with Minikube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-to-use-local-docker-images-with-minikube)

And as per this I ran `eval $(minikube docker-env)`, but I still get this error.

Is what I am trying to do possible or do I need to push this to docker hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `eval $(minikube docker-env)` you will get the docker-engine of the minikube installation.

In some environments, your local docker-engine could be the same one with minikube, however in most cases it's not. It depends on the [drivers](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) settings if the both engines are same.

In case where the engines are different, you will need to set the minikube environment with `eval $(minikube docker-env)` and than build the image.