# How to setup a pull-through local registry that persists images on local machine? (for slow internet access)

Tags: docker, proxy, minikube, docker-registry, docker-volume

#### How to create a local-registry container, that **mounts a volume from the host machine and persist locally all the images that get pulled?**

I want **to not download images more than once**, if not necessary, even after the registry (or the whole Docker VM) is being thrown away and recreated.
This is useful when having slow connection or no connectivity. Would also allow to mount a backup with pre-downloaded images, as `docker volume`, skipping altogether the need for an internet connection.
This latter is already possible, but it would be more convenient than having to manually `docker push`/`docker pull` onto the local registry, or to `docker save`/`docker load` each image that need to be available there.

---

*It's a rephrasing on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67028514/how-to-locally-backup-the-images-of-a-local-docker-registry), that wasn't reopened because of lack of feedback. Main purpose is to make the answer available for search, but feel free to propose better solutions.*

Answer (score 3):

Here are the step-by-step instructions. Hopefully will save time & make life easier to somebody else, travelling or living in disadvantaged areas of the world where internet connections can't access the Docker world, because they are too limited or sometime absent altogether!

Istructions are for *macOS* and *Minikube* but can be adapted also for VM running on *Windows* or via *Docker Desktop*.
(**note:** you will need to check if your virtualization technology provides automount of the system user directory)

---

## Configuration

Define first your environment variables with the desired values. See env-vars in the code below (`PROXIED_REGISTRY`, `REGISTRY_USERNAME`, `REGISTRY_PASSWORD`, `PATH_WHERE_TO_PERSIST_IMAGES`, etc.)

## On the host machine

### Minikube

***If using minikube, first bind to docker on its VM's***

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

or run the commands directly from inside the VM, via `minikube ssh`.

### Create local registry

(note: some envs might be unnecessary; check Docker docs to see what you need)

The `-v` option mounts onto the local registry the path where you want to persist the registry data (repositories folders and image layers).
When you use *Minikube*, this latter [will automatically mount the home folder from the host](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/#driver-mounts) (`/Users/`, on *macOS*) onto the virtual machine where *Docker* is run.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 \
    -e STANDALONE=false \
    -e "REGISTRY_LOG_LEVEL=debug" \
    -e "REGISTRY_REDIRECT_DISABLE=true" \
    -e MIRROR_SOURCE="https://${PROXIED_REGISTRY}" \
    -e REGISTRY_PROXY_REMOTEURL="https://${PROXIED_REGISTRY}" \
    -e REGISTRY_PROXY_USERNAME="${REGISTRY_USER}" \
    -e REGISTRY_PROXY_PASSWORD="${REGISTRY_PASSWORD}" \
    -v /Users/${MACOS_USERNAME}/${PATH_WHERE_TO_PERSIST_IMAGES}/docker/registry:/var/lib/registry \
    --restart=always \
    --name local-registry \
    registry:2
```

### Login to your local registry

```
echo -n "${REGISTRY_PASSWORD}" | docker login -u "${REGISTRY_USER}" --password-stdin "localhost:5000"
```

#### (optional) Verify that the persist directories are present

```
docker exec registry ls -la /var/lib/registry/docker/registry
ll /Users/${MACOS_USERNAME}/${PATH_WHERE_TO_PERSIST_IMAGES}/docker/registry/docker/registry
```

### Try to pull one image from your private registry

(to see it proxied through the repository `localhost:5000`)

```
docker pull localhost:5000/${REPOSITORY}/${IMAGE}:${IMAGE_TAG}
```

#### (optional) Verify the image data has been synced on local host, where desired

```
docker exec registry ls -la /var/lib/registry/docker/registry
ll /Users/${MACOS_USERNAME}/${PATH_WHERE_TO_PERSIST_IMAGES}/docker/registry/docker/registry
```

## If using Kubernetes

change the deployment `spec` container `image` to:

```
localhost:5000/${REPOSITORY}/${IMAGE}:${IMAGE_TAG}
```

*Et voila!*
You now can keep the images downloaded from your repository stored onto your host machine!
If internet is available, the local registry will ensure to have the most recent version of your pulled images, requesting it to the proxied registry (private, or the the Docker hub).

And you will have a last resort backup to run your container also when your internet connection is too slow for re-downloading everything you need, or is unavailable altogether!
(really useful with *Minikube*, when you need to destroy your docker virtual machine)

---

#### References:

- https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/#run-a-registry-as-a-pull-through-cache
- https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/#driver-mounts