# How to use docker image in docker desktop for terraform kubenetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, terraform

I have built my docker image in Docker desktop but I do not know how to config so that terraform kubernetes can refer to local image? (it stuck while creating the pod)

Here is my tf file look like

```
....
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = "~/.kube/config"
}

resource "kubernetes_pod" "test" {
  metadata {
    name = "backend-api"
    labels = {
      app = "MyNodeJsApp"
    }
  }
  spec {
    container {
      image = "backendnodejs:0.0.1"
      name = "backendnodejs-container"
      # I think it keep pulling from Docker Hub 
      port {
        container_port = 5000
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "test" {
  metadata {
    name = "backendnodejs-service"
  }

  spec {
    selector = {
      app = kubernetes_pod.test.metadata.0.labels.app
    }

    port {
      port = 5000
      target_port = 5000
    }

    type = "LoadBalancer"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your Kubernetes cluster running? Usually you'll need to push the image to a container registry (like Docker Hub) so that the Kubernetes node can pull the image.

Comment: I downloaded minikube to my windows machine and use it locally. Is there a way to avoid container registry?

Comment: You can push the image directly to the minikube Docker registry - see https://shashanksrivastava.medium.com/how-to-set-up-minikube-to-use-your-local-docker-registry-10a5b564883

Answer (score 1):

So after hours researching how to deploy to minikube (installed on minikube website not docker desktop kubernetes). I found out that minikube ran as container itself in docker desktop which is why you can not use images from docker desktop to deploy into minikube.

Here are the link solved about this:

- [Pushing images from minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/)
- [How to use local docker images with Minikube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-to-use-local-docker-images-with-minikube)

So things you will need before using terraform deploy to minikube:

1. Pushing directly to the in-cluster Docker daemon (docker-env)

   - **Windows**

     - Powershell

       ```
       PS> & minikube -p minikube docker-env --shell powershell | Invoke-Expression
       ```
     - CMD

       ```
       CMD> @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env --shell cmd') DO @%i
       ```
   - **Linux/MacOS**

     ```
     > eval $(minikube docker-env)
     ```
2. Build docker image again (same terminal that been entered command above)

   ```
   docker build -t your_image_tag your_docker_file
   ```
3. Run normal terraform file (same terminal)

[This link](https://shashanksrivastava.medium.com/how-to-set-up-minikube-to-use-your-local-docker-registry-10a5b564883) also explained same as above