# Configure knative serving to use the local Docker image

Tags: kubernetes, docker-image, knative, knative-serving

How do we configure the knative serving to use the local docker image?

If we need to pull the image from the Google Cloud registry, we append "gcr.io/" as a prefix to the image name. Similarly, is there any prefix to be used for the local image?

I'm facing the below error when I use hello:latest as image name and Never as imagePullPolicy

`Revision "hello1-ld62x" failed with message: Unable to fetch image "hello:latest"`

But the same image is working fine if I use the Kubernetes Deployment resource.

Comment: What do you mean by "local registry"? Do you mean the local registry e.g. from minikube?

Comment: yes, images present in minikube environment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42564211/1560953 is working for Deployments and ReplicaSets but not incase of knativeServing

Comment: Haven't tested it, but on https://github.com/knative/serving/issues/6101 somebody had the same/a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Try add `docker.io` in registries-skipping-tag-resolving. How to add check here:https://knative.dev/docs/serving/configuration/deployment/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).