# istio bookinfo sample application deployment failed for "ImagePullBackOff"

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, istio, minikube

I am trying to deploy **istio's sample bookinfo application** using the below command:

```
kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml
```

from [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/#bookinfo)

but each time I am getting **ImagePullBackoff error** like this:

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
details-v1-c74755ddf-m878f        2/2     Running            0          6m32s
productpage-v1-778ddd95c6-pdqsk   2/2     Running            0          6m32s
ratings-v1-5564969465-956bq       2/2     Running            0          6m32s
reviews-v1-56f6655686-j7lb6       1/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          6m32s
reviews-v2-6b977f8ff5-55tgm       1/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          6m32s
reviews-v3-776b979464-9v7x5       1/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          6m32s
```

For error details, I have run :

```
kubectl describe pod reviews-v1-56f6655686-j7lb6
```

Which returns these:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  7m41s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/reviews-v1-56f6655686-j7lb6 to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     7m39s                  kubelet            Container image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.15.3" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    7m39s                  kubelet            Created container istio-init
  Normal   Started    7m39s                  kubelet            Started container istio-init
  Warning  Failed     5m39s                  kubelet            Failed to pull image "docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v1:1.17.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded
  Warning  Failed     5m39s                  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   Pulled     5m39s                  kubelet            Container image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.15.3" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    5m39s                  kubelet            Created container istio-proxy
  Normal   Started    5m39s                  kubelet            Started container istio-proxy
  Normal   BackOff    5m36s (x3 over 5m38s)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v1:1.17.0"
  Warning  Failed     5m36s (x3 over 5m38s)  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    5m25s (x2 over 7m38s)  kubelet            Pulling image "docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v1:1.17.0"
```

Do I need to build dockerfile first and push it to the local repository? There are no clear instructions there or I failed to find any.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

If you check in dockerhub the image is there:

https://hub.docker.com/r/istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v1/tags

So the error that you need to deal with is `context deadline exceeded` while trying to pull it from dockerhub. This is likely a networking error (a generic Go error saying it took too long), depending on where your cluster is running you can do manually a docker pull from the nodes and that should work.

EDIT: for minikube do a minikube ssh and then a docker pull

Comment: Already tried by docker pull istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v1:latest ( with version also ) but no luck yet

Comment: need to use minikube ssh, it solved my problem

Comment: I will add it to my answer then, great!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the problem by below command :**

```
 minikube ssh docker pull istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v1:1.17.0
```

from this git issues [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/14806)

Also [How to use local docker images with Minikube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-to-use-local-docker-images-with-minikube)

Hope this may help somebody