# Not able to pull local docker image in minikube cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, minikube, docker-registry

I have created a process_file.py file with content:

```
def fun():
    print('My name is sumit lohan')

fun()
```

A dockerfile with content:

```
FROM python:3.9
COPY process_file.py /code/
```

A my-deployment.yaml with content:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: localhost:5000/my-image:latest
        command: ["python", "process_file.py"]
```

I build docker image using:

```
docker build -t my-image .
```

Ran registry container and mapped to port 5000 using:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2
```

Created a tag using:

```
docker tag my-image localhost:5000/my-image
```

and pushed image:

```
docker push localhost:5000/my-image
```

and called `kubectl apply -f my-deployment.yaml`
but getting error that: `container "my-pod1" in pod "my-pod1" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image`

in my docker ps output: i had 2 containers named registry and minikube
i created network and added both conatiners in that network and used registry ip address in image at place of localhost but that also didn't worked

Can somebody help me find the issue and what shall i use to pull image correctly?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve with the `registry` container, but you could just use `my-image:latest` instead of `localhost:5000/my-image:latest` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the `minikube image load` command to **load** the image
   which is built on a local machine.

   Example in your case

> $ minikube image load localhost:5000/my-image

**Note:** If a pod is deployed before loading the image you can restart the pod after loading the image into minikube, so that it will pull the image properly.

2. The other way is you can **build** the image inside minikube using the
   following command. In this way the image is not required to load.

> $ minikube image build -t localhost:5000/my-image

For more detailed information refer to the [minikube image](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/image/#minikube-image-build) page

Comment: Hi @SUMIT did you get a chance to look at this answer? is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a 'secret' with your existing credentials for your local docker where the image resides.  Make sure you create the secret in the same namespace or default namespace depending on where you plan on running your pods.

Follow these steps and check if it works:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Answer (score -1):

To do what you say, I think it isn't necessary to push the Docker image into a Registry running on a Node where the Pod that will use it will also run.

Check out this procedure:
[How to use local docker images with Minikube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564058/how-to-use-local-docker-images-with-minikube)

If you want to create a tool-chain entirely on Kubernetes, you should create a Deployment that uses a Docker image of one of the most famous existing Docker Registries, configure it and then push your custom images in there.

After that all your Deployments will point to the local svc (infra-cluster DNS).

Obviously this architecture holds up as long as we talk about Dev environments; because otherwise you would need Ingress, certificates, .dockerconfigjson (assuming the infrastructure below is Production ready).